# Como formatar data no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, data

Quero jogar a data atual num `input`, mas no formato "brasileiro" `dd/mm/yyyy`.

Meu código:

```
var data = new Date();
dataFormatada = ?????
$("#Data").val(dataFormatada);
```

Comment: Ontem a noite eu estava pensando nisso! Seria muito interessante se houvesse uma abordagem parecida com o `SimpleDateFormat` do Java ou `date` do PHP.

Comment: Regex mais pratico http://stackoverflow.com/a/15504877/2777092 ou usar metodo http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Você pode utilizar uma função para o feito, a fim de simplificar o seu trabalho:

```js
function dataAtualFormatada(){
    var data = new Date(),
        dia  = data.getDate().toString(),
        diaF = (dia.length == 1) ? '0'+dia : dia,
        mes  = (data.getMonth()+1).toString(), //+1 pois no getMonth Janeiro começa com zero.
        mesF = (mes.length == 1) ? '0'+mes : mes,
        anoF = data.getFullYear();
    return diaF+"/"+mesF+"/"+anoF;
}
```

Para `dd/mm/yyyy`.

## Exemplo:

Dia de hoje(resultado do código acima) em um `<input type=text id=Data>`:

```
$('#Data').val(dataAtualFormatada);
```

Teria como resultado o seguinte, no valor do input:

> 19/02/2014

#### Update: no [ES8 (ECMAScript 2017)](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/) foi implementado o método [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart), por isso a solução pode ser utilizada de forma mais simples:

```
function dataAtualFormatada(){
    var data = new Date(),
        dia  = data.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0'),
        mes  = (data.getMonth()+1).toString().padStart(2, '0'), //+1 pois no getMonth Janeiro começa com zero.
        ano  = data.getFullYear();
    return dia+"/"+mes+"/"+ano;
}
```

### Observação:

Esta última solução não funcionará no Internet Explorer e em browsers que não tiverem suporte a ES8, para mais informações consulte [a tabela de compatibilidade](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart#Browser_compatibility).

### Polyfill

```
// https://github.com/uxitten/polyfill/blob/master/string.polyfill.js
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart
if (!String.prototype.padStart) {
    String.prototype.padStart = function padStart(targetLength, padString) {
        targetLength = targetLength >> 0; //truncate if number, or convert non-number to 0;
        padString = String(typeof padString !== 'undefined' ? padString : ' ');
        if (this.length >= targetLength) {
            return String(this);
        } else {
            targetLength = targetLength - this.length;
            if (targetLength > padString.length) {
                padString += padString.repeat(targetLength / padString.length); //append to original to ensure we are longer than needed
            }
            return padString.slice(0, targetLength) + String(this);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: O único problema dessa abordagem é que se o dia ou o mês tiver um único dígito, fica sem zero à esquerda.

Comment: isso é uma verdade, obrigado por lembrar @mgibsonbr

Comment: Agora não tem mais este problema @mgibsonbr

Comment: Mas e o dia!?!?

Comment: opsss @utluiz pera aí - pronto. haha

Comment: Atrevo-me a apontar o caso dos anos anteriores a `1000`? :P (bem que JavaScript podia ter um jeito fácil para fazer *padding* com zeros à esquerda...)

Comment: ah @mgibsonbr aí não né ? auhauhau mas concordo contigo cara, deveria ter ... esse javascript ainda me mata do coração..

Comment: @mgibsonbr Nunca vi zero-padding em anos (em strings com o propósito de serem lidas por humanos)

Comment: Se fizer isso $("#Data").val(dataAtualFormatada); funciona? ou tenho que preencher a variavel antes assim: dataAtualFormatada = dataAtualFormatada(); ?

Comment: Sim @JoaoPaulo, funciona apenas com `$("#Data").val(dataAtualFormatada);`. Editei minha pergunta colocando este exato exemplo para melhor entendimento.

Comment: @PauloRoberto uau, não conhecia essa funcionalidade do `val` (passar uma função pra atualizar o valor corrente), bom saber que ela existe! E quanto ao zero-padding dos anos, sei lá como deveria ser (com ou sem), mas não existem muitas aplicações práticas que mexem com dados históricos e para as quais isso faria muita diferença, então tanto faz... Coloquei o comentário mais como piada.

Answer (score 65):

Use as funções nativas do Javascript:

```
var data = new Date();
console.log(data.toLocaleDateString());
```

Referência: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: muito prático e ainda por cima nativo, valeu!

Comment: essa sem dúvida é a melhor resposta e deveria ter sido escolhida como correta por adotar uma solução nativa da linguagem, sem necessidade de implementação de novas funções e bibliotecas de terceiros.

Comment: Melhor resposta!

Comment: Resolve, porém se estiver do lado client talvez ele não pegue a formatação DD/MM/YYYY por conta do locale. Para permanecer com esse padrão é bom passar o locale `data.toLocaleDateString("pt-BR")`. Mas sem dúvida foi a melhor resposta :D

Comment: Cara, simplesmente sensacional!!

Comment: Só para complementar, utilizando a função data.toLocaleTimeString() você consegue também a hora:minuto:segundo formatado bonitinho. 
Essa é a melhor resposta dessa pergunta e deveria ser setada como a principal.
Javascript nativo, sem jQuery e sem firulas.

Answer (score 42):

Para quem não quiser reinventar a roda, existe a biblioteca [moments.js](http://momentjs.com/), que cuida disso e de várias outras operações envolvendo datas em JavaScript. Entre as funções do moment está a formatação de datas em formatos que podem ser montados como strings. Exemplo de uso:

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
moment().format('dddd');
moment().format("MMM Do YY");
moment().format('YYYY [escaped] YYYY');
moment().format();
```

Note que usar uma biblioteca como essa pode ser um exagero, se a sua necessidade for somente formatar datas, em um único formato.

Comment: É raro vocês me verem postar sugestões de biblioteca aqui, eu gosto mesmo é de código puro. Mas esta achei que valia a pena.

Comment: Interessante, porém achei meio estranho de entender, sei lá.

Comment: Eu fiz essa mesma recomendação [no SOE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21816132/664577) esses dias. A maneira de fazer as coisas lembra muito o [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) do Java e [Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) do .NET.

Comment: Uma nota para quem pretende usar Moment.js no futuro: *Moment was built for the previous era of the JavaScript ecosystem. The modern web looks much different these days.*, presente na própria [documentação do Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/). Então se for adicionar essa dependência **agora** no projeto, pense duas vezes e tente fazer sem :)

Answer (score 22):

Se você estiver usando jQuery UI, pode usar uma função auxiliar do `datepicker`:

```
$.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', new Date())
```

(Nota: acrescentei essa resposta pois vi no seu código de exemplo o uso de jQuery, ainda que a pergunta fosse sobre JavaScript puro. Cabe também notar que o jQuery simples não possui `datepicker`, apenas o jQuery UI)

Comment: Boa opção. Precisa so de 'yy' para mostrar 2014?

Comment: @JoaoPaulo Sim. Não sei se sequer existe opção de formatar ano com dois dígitos...

Comment: Eu consegui mostrar ano com dois dígitos usando 'dd/mm/y'. Funcionou, e aparentemente não acarretou em maiores problemas, pelo menos no meu código

Answer (score 9):

> ("0" + data.getDate()).substr(-2) // Garante que haverá zero se < 9

No seu caso, seria

```
var data = new Date();
var dataFormatada = ("0" + data.getDate()).substr(-2) + "/" 
    + ("0" + (data.getMonth() + 1)).substr(-2) + "/" + data.getFullYear();
```

Formatar data em Javascript pode ser feito em apenas uma linha de código se você fizer um pad com "0" e `substr`. A maioria das pessoas nunca parou pra ver que isso é genial. Descobri isso alguns anos atrás no SO internacional, em uma pergunta.

### Vantagens de formatar com "0" e `substr`

- Código curto e direto
- Menos IFs
- Menos variáveis criadas
- Pesa menos do que uma biblioteca apenas para manipular datas

### Desvantagens

- Em situações que tem que trabalhar com muitos formatos diferentes, uso de bibliotecas especificas é mais simples

---

### Alternativa com toISOString

Uma alternativa mais legível é toISOString, porém ela não tem suporte em IE8

```
var data = new Date();
console.log(data.toISOString().substr(0, 10).split('-').reverse().join('/'));
```

[Documentação do Date.prototype.toISOString() no MDN,com Polyfill para navegadores sem suporte](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

Comment: E as desvantagens? :p

Comment: @PauloRoberto Não trivial de ler. E quebra o limite de colunas que alguns gostam de ter em cada linha. Só estilo mesmo.

Comment: Isso é um snippet. Ou entende o conceito de substr e lembra na hora, ou você copia e cola um codigo pronto. Quanto a ser trivial de ler, bem, isso é javascript puro. Não é uma biblioteca inteira que aplica regex pra formatar uma data, então não vejo tanto problema assim em não ser legível. Aliás, reparem que ela deve funcionar até em IE5

Comment: Na verdade eu acho bem legível.

Comment: É.. retiro o "não trivial de ler". Apenas não estou tão familiarizado com JS e vi uma linha grande demais :)

Answer (score 6):

Utilizei a resposta do Paulo Roberto como base (ainda nao tinha implementação do zero nos meses com um digito) e fiz assim:

```
var data = new Date();

var dia  = data.getDate();
if (dia< 10) {
    dia  = "0" + dia;
}

var mes  = data.getMonth() + 1;
if (mes < 10) {
    mes  = "0" + mes;
}

var ano  = data.getFullYear();
dataFormatada = dia + "/" + mes + "/" + ano;
$("#Data").val(dataFormatada);
```

Adicionando o zero nos meses com um digito.

Comment: porém eu fui mais rápido e editei e coloquei o zero nos meses, haha. +1 pra você pois está correto. e achei interessante o seu `(mes < 10)` eu utilizei a length do mes transformada pra string =x

Comment: para if's que contenham apenas uma linha de código à executar você não precisa de braces que seriam `{` e `}`

Comment: E realmente o dia também precisa desse if! Quando o SO deixar, marcarei a sua como questão respondida. Obrigado @Paulo Roberto! Sim eu sei sobre braces, mas gosto de utiliza-los pois pra mim fica mais claro o código.

Comment: De nada, disponha meu caro @JoaoPaulo :)

Answer (score 6):

Complementando as outras respostas...

Você menciona "formato brasileiro" e logo em seguida "dd/mm/yyyy". Apesar de serem "a mesma coisa" (já que é o formato mais comum no Brasil), existem algumas considerações quanto aos métodos usados nas outras respostas. Vejamos:

---

## `toLocaleDateString`

[Uma das respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/58089/112052) sugere usar `toLocaleDateString()` sem parâmetros. Isso **pode ou não funcionar**, já que este método, quando chamado sem parâmetros, usa o *locale* que estiver configurado no ambiente onde o código roda (que pode ser a configuração do *browser*, ou, no caso do Node, a configuração do sistema operacional/shell).

Por exemplo, o código abaixo:

```
var date = new Date();
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString());
```

Rodei este código hoje (9 de fevereiro de 2021, 21:00 no Horário de Brasília) no Node em uma máquina Ubuntu configurado em inglês. Rodando o código acima, o resultado foi `2/9/2021` (o *irritante* formato americano, com o mês antes do dia, e sem os zeros à esquerda para valores menores que 10).

Então para ter certeza que o formato brasileiro será usado, você tem que informar o *locale* (no caso, `pt-BR`, que equivale ao português brasileiro):

```
date.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR')
```

Aí sim será usado o formato correto, e a saída será `09/02/2021`.

No Node, também é possível setar no início do script (obs: não funciona no Windows):

```
process.env.LANG="pt-BR.utf8";
// restante do código
```

Nesse caso, chamar `toLocaleDateString()` sem parâmetros irá usar o *locale* `pt-BR` e o formato brasileiro será usado. Mas isso muda também a configuração de todas as funções que usam o *locale default* do ambiente (como o [`toLocaleString()` para números](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString), entre outros), e isso nem sempre pode ser o desejado. Então se você já sabe qual *locale* quer usar, melhor passá-lo diretamente como parâmetro, sem precisar mudar uma configuração que pode afetar outras partes.

---

Mas tem um detalhe: se o *locale* não estiver instalado, isso não garante que será usado o formato correto. Por exemplo, o [Node < 13 não vinha com os *locales* instalados](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/8500#issuecomment-556520467), então mesmo usando `pt-BR`, era feito o *fallback* para o formato americano. E também há a possibilidade - mais rara, mas ainda sim possível - do formato associado ao *locale* mudar.

---

#### Pra não dizer que não respondi com algo novo...

E só para constar, uma alternativa que não foi contemplada nas outras respostas: é possível usar [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat):

```js
var formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('pt-BR');
var date = new Date();
console.log(formatter.format(date));
```

Ele funciona de maneira similar à `toLocaleDateString()`, porém [segundo a documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString#performance), `Intl.DateTimeFormat` tem melhor desempenho quando você precisa formatar muitas datas (bastando criar apenas um e usar o método `format`).

---

## Formato fixo

Outra possibilidade, para não depender do *locale* `pt-BR` estar instalado no ambiente onde o código roda, é formatar a data manualmente.

Várias respostas usam os *getters* para obter os valores do dia, mês e ano, e em seguida constroem a string, e [uma em particular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/417433/112052) usa [`toISOString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) para obter esses mesmos valores. **Esse é um caso em que deve-se tomar cuidado**, pois `toISOString` retorna a data em [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), enquanto os *getters* retornam os valores com base no timezone do ambiente (browser/SO).

Veja um exemplo que faz diferença (**atenção, deve-se rodar o código abaixo em um browser configurado no Horário de Brasília, senão os resultados poderão ser diferentes**):

```js
function pad(valor) { // completa com zero à esquerda, se necessário
    return valor.toString().padStart(2, '0');
}

// 9 de de fevereiro de 2021, às 23:00
var date = new Date(2021, 1, 9, 23, 0);

// usando toLocaleDateString
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR')); // 09/02/2021

// usando os getters
console.log(`${pad(date.getDate())}/${pad(date.getMonth() + 1)}/${pad(date.getFullYear())}`); // 09/02/2021

// usando o código da outra resposta (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/417433/112052)
console.log(date.toISOString().match(/^[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}/)[0].split('-').reverse().join('/')); // 10/02/2021
```

Se o seu browser está configurado para o Horário de Brasília (o Chrome e o Firefox pegam do sistema operacional, os demais não tenho certeza), então vai notar que os 2 primeiros retornaram a data correta (`09/02/2021`), enquanto `toISOString` retornou um dia depois (`10/02/2021`).

Isso acontece porque `toISOString` retorna a data e hora em [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), enquanto `toLocaleDateString` e os *getters* retornam os valores usando-se o timezone do browser. E como *9 de de fevereiro de 2021, às 23:00 no Horário de Brasília* equivale a ***10** de de fevereiro de 2021, às 02:00 em UTC*, temos essa diferença. Então este é um ponto de atenção, caso decida-se usar `toISOString` (lembrando que em fusos horários diferentes, as datas/horas em que isso ocorre podem variar - em alguns casos, pode até retornar uma dia antes, por exemplo).

De resto, uma vez tendo os valores (seja em UTC ou no timezone do browser), as outras respostas já te dão muitas opções para formatá-los, e sobre este ponto específico não há muito o que acrescentar.

Answer (score 4):

Com base nesta pergunta montei um pequeno [git](https://github.com/Lautert/helpers/blob/master/javascript.helpers.js) com algumas funções auxiliares para estes fins.

Usando os métodos que disponibilizei pode se fazer assim :

```js
var d = new Date();
console.log(d.toDate('dd/mm/yyyy hh:ii:ss'));

console.log(d.toDate('mm/dd/yyyy hh:ii:ss'));

console.log(d.toDate('yyyy-mm-dd'));

console.log(d.toDate('yyyy-dd'));
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/Lautert/helpers/master/javascript.helpers.js"></script>
```

Comment: https://rawgit.com/Lautert/helpers/master/javascript.helpers.js não está mais disponível

Comment: @durtto aqui anda esta online, tem certeza que não é bloqueio de acesso?

Answer (score 4):

```js
function formatDate(data, formato) {
  if (formato == 'pt-br') {
    return (data.substr(0, 10).split('-').reverse().join('/'));
  } else {
    return (data.substr(0, 10).split('/').reverse().join('-'));
  }
}

console.log(formatDate('23/04/2018'));
console.log(formatDate('2018-04-01', 'pt-br'));
```

Comment: A pergunta questiona como formatar um objeto `Date`, então acredito que falte em sua resposta a parte onde converte tal objeto para *string*, visto que sua função só funciona para *string*.

Comment: var dataAtual = new Date();

console.log(formatDate(dataAtual.toISOString(), 'pt-br'));

Answer (score 4):

```
new Date(myDateString).toLocaleDateString('pt-br');
```

Exemplo:

```
console.log(new Date('2021/01/07').toLocaleDateString('pt-br'));
"07/01/2021"
```

Tente isso

Answer (score 1):

Você pode formatar usando `template string`:

```js
const formatar = (data) => {
  const ano = data.getFullYear();
  const mes = (`00${data.getMonth() + 1}`).slice(-2);
  const dia = (`00${data.getDate()}`).slice(-2);

  return `${dia}/${mes}/${ano}`;
};

// Teste da função
console.log(formatar(new Date()));
```

---

> [`Template String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)
>
> Template literals são literais string que permitem expressões embutidas. Você pode usar string multi-linhas e interpolação de string com elas. Elas eram chamadas "template strings" nas versões anteriores à especificação ES2015.
>
> **Sintaxe**
>
> ```
> `corpo de texto`
> `texto linha 1
>  texto linha 2`
> `texto string ${expression} texto string`
> tag `texto string ${expression} texto string`
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log( (new Date()).toISOString().match(/^[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}/)[0].split('-').reverse().join('/') )
```