# Group by com linq

Tags: c#, linq

Tenho as seguintes tabelas:

```
**Aula**
Id
Nome
Data

**Avaliacao**
Aula_Id
Aluno_Id
Organizacao
Didatica
```

Para obter um join das tabelas utilizo o código:

```
var result = from a in mdc.SBE_AA_Aulas
             join av in mdc.SBE_AA_AvaliacaoAlunos on a.id equals av.SBE_AA_Aula_id

             select new
             {
               a,
               av
             };
```

Onde **Organizacao** e **Didatica** são as notas.

Queria uma consulta através do linq, que trouxesse uma média das notas de **Organizacao** e **Didatica** de cada aula.

Porém não consigo fazer isso.

Comment: Você tem um código inicial onde você obtém os objetos de aulas e avaliações?

Comment: Adicionei no post!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assim funciona, mas não tenho certeza se é a melhor maneira:

```
var result = from a in mdc.SBE_AA_Aulas
            join av in mdc.SBE_AA_AvaliacaoAlunos on a.id equals av.SBE_AA_Aula_id
            group new {a, av} by av.Aula_Id into grp
            select new {
                NomeAula = grp.Select(x => x.a.Nome).FirstOrDefault(),
                MediaOrganizacao = grp.Average(x => x.av.Organizacao),
                MediaDidatica = grp.Average(x => x.av.Didatica)
            }
```

Comment: Não entendi o que é "av.CodWsUsuario"

Comment: Opa! Corrigido!

Comment: Você está usando Ajax certo? Para formatar a data corretamente veja essa questão: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6526

Comment: Ok @André. Obrigado!