# Transformar data americana para brasil em js

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

Tenho a seguinte data em `JS` : `2015-03-26T16:22-04:00` qual código posso usar para transformar ela no formato brasileiro?

Comment: E como é o formato Brasileiro?

Comment: Possivel duplicata: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6526/129

Comment: no exemplo seria: 26/03/2015, a hora nao sei pq tem akele hifen

Comment: Dá uma olhada na resposta que linkei, se achares que foi em erro voltamos a abrir.

Comment: @Sergio na verdade ela é similar não igual, pois no exemplo dele tem o `-04:00`, ou seja esta data esta em UTC, o resultado seria `26/03/2015 12:22:00`, pois se deve diminuir 4h.

Comment: exato @GuilhermeLautert teria que ficar desse jeito, como posso fazer?