# Como formatar a data de um input[date] no formato dd/mm/yyyy'?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tenho uma página, construída com AngularJS, que possuí um [input[type=date]](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D).

Basicamente, o que eu quero é pegar essa data e formatar (ou seja, exibir para o usuário) usando o formato `'dd/MM/yyyy'` (por exemplo: `28/05/2015`).

**Qual o problema?**

Hoje, [não são todos os browsers que suportam o `input[type=date]`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime). Aqueles que suportam (como o Chrome e o Opera) formatam a data do `input` no formato `'dd/MM/yyyy'`, de acordo com as configurações do próprio navegador.

Já nos navegadores que não suportam (como o Firefox e o Safari), o Angular usa o formato `yyyy-MM-dd` para formatar a data do `input`. Esse formato, que apesar de ser legível, pode não agradar os usuários da aplicação, que estão acostumados com o formato brasileiro.

**Qual a solução?**

Em resumo, não consegui achar nenhuma forma de solucionar isso.

O Angular não possuí nenhuma [diretiva](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D) para setar o formato do input. Então, tentei implementar uma diretiva que faça essa trabalho para mim, seguindo alguns posts do SO-EN:

- [Angular.js and HTML5 date input value — how to get Firefox to show a readable date value in a date input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18061757/angular-js-and-html5-date-input-value-how-to-get-firefox-to-show-a-readable-d)
- [AngularJs - Directive to modify input formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768714/angularjs-directive-to-modify-input-formatting)
- [How to format a date using ng-model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474555/how-to-format-a-date-using-ng-model)

O resultado disso foi a seguinte diretiva:

```
module.directive("input", ["$filter", function($filter) {
    return {
        require: "ngModel",
        restrict: "E",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
            if (element.attr("type") != "date") {
                return;
            }

            if (verificaSeNavegadorNaoSuportaInputDate()) {
                ngModelController.$parsers.push(function(dataEmString) {
                    return converteStringParaData(dataEmString);
                });

                ngModelController.$formatters.push(function(data) {
                    return formataDataParaString(data);
                });
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

Com essa diretiva, eu até consigo formatar a data setada no model, **mas não consigo transformar a entrada do usuário em um objeto `Date`**. Mais precisamente o `$validator` `date` do [NgModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) falha, já que, supostamente, o valor do `input` não é uma data.

Para tentar ilustrar: usando a diretiva acima, o valor de `form.inputDoTipoDate.$error.date` é igual a `true`.

Alguém tem ideia de como posso implementar/corrigir essa diretiva?

Comment: Vê se ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6526/como-formatar-data-no-javascript.

Comment: Hehe, valeu pelo link. Mas o problema é com o tratamento do Angular.

Comment: Ok, é que lembrei de um outro tópico, mas não achei, daí achei esse e pensei que pudesse ajudar... mas mesmo esse outro que pensei não tratava de angular.

Comment: Use o [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) tanto para exibir quanto para receber(converter) o valor, não tem erro.

Comment: NÃO uses o momentjs para isso. Odeio gente que para matar uma mosca sugere um canhão só porque a marca do canhão está na voga...    
O que tu tens que fazer é um filtro, que retorna a data como tu queres, e chamares esse filtro ao que está a ser feito no input.

Comment: Minha sugestão é [http://720kb.github.io/angular-datepicker/](http://720kb.github.io/angular-datepicker/)

Comment: Depois é só usar: `<datepicker date-format="dd-MM-yyyy" date-min-limit="{{hoje}}">`

Comment: Utilize ui-bootstrap (bootstrap escrito em AngularJs). Tem um datepicker pontinho que resolve seu problema

Comment: Tudo o que é necessário saber está bem explicado no link a seguir: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker

Answer (score 2):

```js
//Com js pode fazer da seguinte forma
// O input type=date vem no seguinte formato yyyy-mm-dd

// Para setar o valor caso esteja no formato dd/mm/yyyy

document.querySelector('[type=date]').value = '08/06/2017'.split('/').reverse().join('-');

// Para transformar de '2017-06-08' (formato devolvido no //document.querySelector('[type=date]').value) para //'08/06/2017'. Pode fazer isso: 

var brDate = '2017-06-08'.split('-').reverse().join('/');
var inputDate = '08/06/2017'.split('/').reverse().join('-');

console.log("br date: " + brDate);
console.log("input date: " + inputDate);
```

```html
<input type="date" />
```

Answer (score 0):

A sua ideia de criar uma directive pode funcionar se utilizar filtros. Eu vi que voce adicionou o **$filter** service no seu codigo, mas vc nao utilizou ele.

Da uma olhada no codigo abaixo:

```
module.directive("input", ["$filter", function($filter) {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
        if (element.attr("type") != "date") {
            return;
        }
        ngModelController.$parsers.push(function(data) {
          //View -> Model
          return data;
       });
       ngModelController.$formatters.push(function(data) {
          //Model -> View
          return $filter('date')(data, "DD-MM-YYYY");
        });
      }
    }
  };
}]);
```

Acho que so ficou faltando voce usar o $filter service na sua directive como eu fiz no codigo acima.

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Comment: Eu usei ele. Só abstraí o uso dele para simplificar o código de exemplo. Mas obrigado pela resposta. =)