# Como mudar o formato do dia em javascript?

Tags: javascript

Boas pessoa, a cena é que eu tenho aqui o script que faz com que ao fazer uma reserva, nao se possa selecionar o dia de ontem, e tal .,.. mas quando vou a ver a data aparece no formato `MM-DD-YYYY` , e nao sei como fazer com que fique `DD-MM-YYYY`

```
//Script para que só se possa selecionar a data de hoje
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#StartDate").datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: "+60D",
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function(selected) {
          $("#txtToDate").datepicker.formatDate("dd-mm-yy","option","minDate", selected)

        }
    });
    //Script para que só se possa selecionar o dia de amanhã e os restantes
    $('#EndDate').datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate:"+60D",
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function(selected) {
           $("#StartDate").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected)
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Boa tarde, use tags relevantes a pergunta e não ao seu projeto todo.

Comment: Relacionado : http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6526/como-formatar-data-no-javascript ?

Answer (score 1):

A API do datepicker tem [uma opção para isso](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat). Tens de passar no objeto de configuração `dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'`. No teu caso o código poderia ser:

```
$("#StartDate").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: "+60D",
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' // <-----------
    // etc...
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/m4qovgkx/

Comment: Muito obrigado. eu tentei meter o dateformat com várias funções, nao pensei que fosse assim tao facil. obrigado mesmo

Comment: @Odacil boa, fico contente de ajudar também.

Comment: se não for pedir muito tem outra maneira de o contactar ? é que gostaria imenso que me ajuda-se. visto que estou a 3 meses a tentar acabar um projecto. Agradeceria imenso se pudesse. obrigado

Comment: @Odacil a ideia do Stackoverflow é criarmos juntos conteúdo que possa ajudar os outros. Pode parecer estranho mas eu tenho tempo para ajudar aqui quando posso mas não tenho tempo para me comprometer em mais projetos. Mas vai perguntando aqui o que não consegues fazer, tentando sempre resolver o problema sozinho antes de perguntar.

Answer (score 1):

Meu amigo, já que estamos falando do padrão `pt-br`, além da resposta dada pelo amigo Sergio, acredito que as edições que eu fiz no link abaixo poderão te ajudar muito.

https://jsfiddle.net/m4qovgkx/1/