# Problemas em conversão de datas JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Eu tenho um sistema hospedado na UOL onde capturo os dados através de um `ajax` do meu `WebService` e as datas que estão no banco estão no formato de `DD/MM/AAAA` porém quando eu retorno para a tela(`HTML`) as datas acabam sendo convertidas para `MM/DD/AAAAA`.

Tem como eu formar sempre a ficar no formato `DD/MM/AAAAA`?

Segue o código @Lucas Costa

Busco informações do WS
try{
        //Requisita no Servidor
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: metodo,
            data: JSON.stringify(parametros),

```
        beforeSend: function(){
            loading.css('visibility', 'visible'); // exibe o div
        },
        complete: function(){
            loading.css('visibility', 'hidden'); // esconde o div
            divLoading.classList.remove('loading');
            divLoading.innerHTML = '';
        },

        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json", //; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (resposta) {
            if (resposta.d !== null && resposta.d !== "") {
                pagina = 0;                
                dados  = resposta.d;                 
            }
```

**Depois eu populo minha tabela

for (var i = 0; i < dados.length; i++){
            cont ++;
            tbody.append(
                $("")

```
            .append($("<td title='Status de viagem: " + dados[i].DscStatus + "'>")
            .append("<button type='button' "+
            "class='btn btn-default btn-sm' onclick='javascript: AbrirRegistroDadosVaigem(" + dados[i].NroViagem + ");'> "+
            "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-road' style='color:" + dados[i].CorStatus +";'></span></button>"))

            .append($("<td>").append("<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm'  data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myCheckList'" +
            " onclick='javascript: AbrirCheckList(" + dados[i].NroViagem + ");'> " +
            "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-list'></span></button>"))

            .append($("<td>").append("<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' " +
            " onclick='javascript: AbrirRegistroFup(" + dados[i].NroViagem + ");'> " +
            "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-envelope badge'> " + dados[i].QtdFup + " </span></button>"))

            .append($("<td>").append("<input type='checkbox' value=''>"))                        
            .append($("<td>").append(dados[i].DataColeta))
            .append($("<td>").append(dados[i].DataEntrega))
```

E o problema sao os campos de DataColeta e DataEntrega que ora ficam como DD/MM/AAAA e ora como MM/DD/AAAA

Comment: Poderia incluir o código ao invés da imagem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O JavaScript possui seu próprio padrão de datas, sendo assim, você precisa converte-las.

Veja aqui, essa resposta resolve seu problema:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6535/5126

Comment: Paulo ja tentei o problema é que ora a data vem como DD/MM/AAAA e ora vem como MM/DD/AAAA. Ja tentei contato com o suporte do UOL e eles informam que nao tem este tipo de condiguracao no IS

Comment: Bem, eu tive um problema parecido com isso, não era em JavaScript, mas talvez seja a mesma coisa. 

O servidor estava configurado com o idioma inglês, meu pc em português. Configurei pra português o servidor. 
Acontece que toda vez que eu subia meu site, o servidor desconfigurava e eu só ia perceber isso depois de um cliente ligar reclamando...

Verifica se não tem como LOCALMENTE você definir a versão do seu site. 
no ASP.NET é possível fazer isso no web.config, assim independente da configuração do idioma do servidor, é possível mante-lo em portuguÊs com a data certa.

Comment: Ótimo. Tentarei isso é retorno. Obrigado.