# Como formatar data em Javascript colocando nome do mês e dia da semana

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, data

Olá.

Tenha essa data: **18/05/17**.

E preciso converte-la para isso: **18 mai (Qui)**

mai: maio, (Qui): Quinta-feira

Alguem sabe como faço isso usando JavaScript e jQuery?

Comment: Recomendo editar a sua pergunta colocando um título mais adequado. Receio que ela seja inclusive duplicada.

Comment: @LeonanCarvalho receio de duplicidade sem o link da pergunta que seria a original é calúnia.

Comment: @Renan, estou pelo aplicativo mobile não consigo colar o link aqui. E outra , receio não é afirmação.

Comment: Possível duplicada de: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6526/como-formatar-data-no-javascript

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Tens de ter guardado os nomes dos dias da semana e do mês. Tendo isso é fácil:

```js
var meses = [
  "Janeiro",
  "Fevereiro",
  "Março",
  "Abril",
  "Maio",
  "Junho",
  "Julho",
  "Agosto",
  "Setembro",
  "Outubro",
  "Novembro",
  "Dezembro"
];
var dias = ["domingo", "Segunda", "Terça", "Quarta", "Quinta", "Sexta", "Sábado"]

function formatarData(str) {
  var partes = str.split('/').map(Number);
  var data = new Date('20' + partes[2], partes[1] - 1, partes[0]);
  var diaSemana = dias[data.getDay() % 7];
  var mes = meses[data.getMonth()];
  return [data.getDate(), mes.slice(0, 3).toLowerCase(), '(' + diaSemana.slice(0, 3) + ')'].join(' ');
}




var data = '18/05/17';
console.log(formatarData(data));
```

Outra opção, mais simples é usares o `Locale`, ou seja as defenições do browser para mostrar datas:

```js
function formatarData(str) {
  var partes = str.split('/').map(Number);
  var data = new Date('20' + partes[2], partes[1] - 1, partes[0]);
  return data.toLocaleString([], { weekday: 'short', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' });
}




var data = '18/05/17';
console.log(formatarData(data));
```

Comment: Boa resposta! Tinha pensado em fazer com dateFormat, mas além de ter o resultado em inglês, ficou muito complicado.

Comment: Thanks my king, very helpful this answer =)

Answer (score 3):

```js
 var meses = [
      "Janeiro",
      "Fevereiro",
      "Março",
      "Abril",
      "Maio",
      "Junho",
      "Julho",
      "Agosto",
      "Setembro",
      "Outubro",
      "Novembro",
      "Dezembro"
    ];
    var days = ['Domingo','Segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado'];
    var data = '18/05/17';
    
    var formatData = data.replace(/(\d{2})(\/)(\d{2})/, "$3$2$1");  
    
    var newData = new Date(formatData);
    
    console.log(newData.getDate() + ' ' + meses[newData.getMonth()] + ' (' +  days[newData.getDay()]+ ')');
```

Comment: Solução bacana, ficou curtinho o código.

Answer (score -2):

Javascript não tem essa funcionalidade nativamente. Sugiro usar uma biblioteca para isso, de preferência [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

Na página no link tem vários exemplos do uso de sua função [format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/). Ao final da página você pode mudar o idioma e ver os mesmos exemplos com resultados em Português.

Não esqueça de baixar além do Moment.js o arquivo de local para [Português de Portugal](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/locale/pt.js) ou [Português do Brasil](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/locale/pt-br.js).

Comment: Realmente javascript nao tem, mas acho que usar moment so para isso e um pouco exagerado. a opcao de um array com os meses em portugues resolve.