# Pegar a data anterior a uma informada

Tags: javascript, jquery, data

```js
var date = '2019-01-01';
var d = new Date( date );
d.setDate( d.getDate() );

document.write(d);
```

**Retornou isso**:

> Mon Dec 31 2018 22:00:00 GMT-0200 (Horário de Verão de Brasília)

Como faço agora para retornar assim:

> 2018/12/31

JavaScript ou jQuery?

Comment: sugiro usar o [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) que faz isso de maneira bem simples, por exemplo `moment().format("yyyy/MM/dd");`

Comment: Acho que encontras aqui o que procuras... https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205086/129

Comment: usar uma biblioteca apenas uma vez não gostaria. É mais facil fazer um explode e depois montar a string. Mas gostara de saber como receber no formato americano

Comment: `d.setDate( d.getDate() )` é redundante e desnecessário, pois vc está setando o mesmo valor que o campo já tem (ou seja, não está mudando nada): https://jsfiddle.net/y3ms2qu1/

Comment: @RicardoPontual Na verdade é `moment().format("YYYY/MM/DD")` (com o `Y` e `D` maiúsculos): https://jsfiddle.net/372uzpmg/1/

Comment: Legal, bem observado @hkotsubo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atenção, [o seu código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/367062/112052) **parece** estar pegando a data do dia anterior, mas foi apenas sorte/coincidência. Vamos entender o que acontece de fato.

---

#### Construtor de `Date`

Quando você passa uma string para o [construtor de `Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), ele se comporta da mesma forma que o método [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse). Este, por sua vez, quando a string tem somente a data, [interpreta a mesma como UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Date_Time_String_Format). Além disso, o horário é setado para meia-noite, ou seja, o código abaixo:

```js
let d = new Date('2019-01-01');
```

Produz uma data equivalente a 1 de janeiro de 2019, à meia-noite, [**em UTC**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

O detalhe é que ao imprimir a data (seja com `console.log`, `document.write`, `alert` ou o que for), ela é mostrada no timezone do browser (que por sua vez usa [o que está configurado no sistema operacional](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16449343)).

No seu caso - e no meu também - o browser está usando o horário de Brasília, e por isso a saída foi:

> Mon Dec 31 2018 22:00:00 GMT-0200 (Brasilia Summer Time)

<sup>*No seu caso foi "Horário de Verão de Brasília" em vez de "Brasilia Summer Time", pois o idioma do seu browser está setado para português, e o meu está em inglês. Mas o que importa é que o timezone utilizado foi o horário oficial de Brasília.*</sup>

Isso acontece porque "1 de janeiro de 2019 à meia-noite em UTC" é igual a "31 de dezembro de 2018 às 22h no horário de Brasília". O instante é o mesmo, mas em diferentes partes do mundo a data e hora podem ser diferentes.

Você pode observar isso se verificar o valor de `getTime()`, que retorna o valor do [*timestamp*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/112052):

```js
let d = new Date('2019-01-01');
console.log(d.getTime()); // 1546300800000
```

O retorno é 1546300800000, que é a quantidade de milissegundos desde o [Unix Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (01/01/1970 à meia-noite em UTC). Este valor representa um único instante que é o mesmo no mundo todo.

O detalhe é que esse mesmo valor pode corresponder a uma data e hora diferente, dependendo do fuso horário em que você está. Em São Paulo, este timestamp corresponde a [31/12/2018 às 22h](https://www.epochconverter.com/timezones?q=1546300800000&tz=America%2FSao_Paulo#convert-tz), mas em Tóquio, esse mesmo timestamp corresponde a [01/01/2019 às 9 da manhã](https://www.epochconverter.com/timezones?q=1546300800000&tz=Asia%2FTokyo#convert-tz).

Usando a data em questão, é possível simular este comportamento simplesmente mudando as configurações de fuso horário do seu computador e fazendo o teste. Quando eu mudei para o fuso horário do Japão, ao imprimir `d` o resultado foi:

> Tue Jan 01 2019 09:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time)

Mas ao mudar o fuso horário de volta para o Brasil, o resultado foi:

> Mon Dec 31 2018 22:00:00 GMT-0200 (Brasilia Summer Time)

Tudo isso sem sequer mudar o valor de `d` (apenas imprimindo novamente). *Pode ser que, dependendo do sistema, você precise reiniciar o browser para que ele pegue o novo fuso horário, mas no meu caso não foi necessário.*

Este mesmo comportamento ocorre com [`toLocaleDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString), que retorna os valores do dia, mês e ano de acordo com o timezone do browser. Novamente, mudando o timezone do meu computador para o do Japão, `d.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR')` retorna:

> 01/01/2019

Voltando a configuração do timezone para o horário do Brasil, o retorno é:

> 31/12/2018

E mais uma vez, sem mudar o valor de `d`. Repare que o parâmetro `'pt-BR'` serve apenas para definir o formato da data (no caso, dia, mês e ano separados por `/`), mas os **valores** do dia, mês e ano dependem do timezone configurado.

E o mesmo comportamento ocorre para os *getters* (como `getDate()`, `getMonth()`, `getHours()`, etc). Então o seu código está extremamente dependente do ambiente no qual ele rodará. Em alguns casos, "funcionará", em outros não. Pode parecer um erro bobo e "*obviamente não vai acontecer comigo, meus clientes são todos do Brasil*", mas depender tanto assim das configurações locais de cada cliente para ter o resultado correto não me parece uma boa abordagem. Ainda mais quando há meios de se resolver.

---

#### Então como resolver?

Já que a data é gerada em UTC, use os métodos `getUTCxxx`, que retornam o valor do dia, mês e ano em UTC (ou seja, seus valores não dependem do timezone do browser).

E como o `Date` gerado possui o horário setado para meia-noite em UTC, basta subtrair 1 do valor de `getTime()`, que a data resultante será o dia anterior às 23:59:59.999 - e como eu só estou interessado no dia, mês e ano, isso é o suficiente.

Em seguida uso os métodos `getUTCxxx` (para obter os valores da data em UTC, assim não dependo do timezone do browser), e uso [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) para completar valores menores que 10 com um zero à esquerda (para escrever o dia 1 como 01, por exemplo).

Outro detalhe chato é que [`getUTCMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCMonth) retorna valores entre 0 e 11 (janeiro é zero, fevereiro é 1, etc), então temos que lembrar de somar 1 (*essa API de datas do JavaScript [é terrível](https://codeofmatt.com/javascript-date-type-is-horribly-broken/)*).

```js
let d = new Date('2019-01-01');
d.setTime(d.getTime() - 1);
console.log(d.getUTCFullYear() + '/' +
            (d.getUTCMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0') + '/' +
            d.getUTCDate().toString().padStart(2, '0')); // 2018/12/31
```

Com isso, o resultado sempre será `2018/12/31`, independente do timezone do browser, já que estamos trabalhando com os valores em UTC.

Se quiser ser bem preciso e subtrair exatamente 1 dia, faça `d.setTime(d.getTime() - (1000 * 3600 * 24))` (isso subtrai a quantidade de milissegundos em um dia, o resultado será meia-noite do dia anterior em UTC). Como estamos trabalhando com os valores da data em UTC, não há problemas com [horário de verão](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/transition.html), e o resultado sempre será o dia anterior ao que foi passado no construtor de `Date`.

---

Se quiser, também pode usar sua solução com `toLocaleDateString`. O único detalhe é que [você pode passar como parâmetro o timezone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString#Parameters), então eu posso passar "UTC" e assim não depender do timezone do browser.

Se você não especificar o timezone, será usado o do browser, que como vimos, não é um valor confiável para o seu caso.

```js
let d = new Date('2019-01-01');
d.setTime(d.getTime() - 1);
let partes = d.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR', { timeZone: 'UTC' }).split("/");
let dia = partes[0];
let mes = partes[1];
let ano = partes[2];
console.log(ano + "/" + mes + "/" + dia); // 2018/12/31
```

Nos browsers mais modernos ([compatíveis com ES6](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)) dá para fazer assim também:

```js
let d = new Date('2019-01-01');
d.setTime(d.getTime() - 1);
let [dia, mes, ano] = d.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR', { timeZone: 'UTC' }).split("/");
console.log(`${ano}/${mes}/${dia}`); // 2018/12/31
```

---

#### Moment.js

Nos comentários você disse que [não quer usar uma biblioteca](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/367052/pegar-a-data-anterior-a-uma-informada#comment731849_367052). Mas a pergunta diz que a solução pode usar jQuery, se for o caso. Bem, vendo os respectivos sites hoje, o arquivo js do [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) tem praticamente a metade do tamanho do [jQuery](https://jquery.com/download/). Se já está usando o jQuery (que hoje em dia, dependendo do caso, [*talvez* nem seja tão necessária](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)), por que não usar uma biblioteca - por sinal, excelente - para lidar especificamente com datas, já que a API nativa [é tão ruim](https://codeofmatt.com/javascript-date-type-is-horribly-broken/)?

Claro que usar uma biblioteca só para um trecho específico pode parecer exagero, mas se for manipular datas em mais pontos do código, pode ser que valha a pena. Fica a seu critério.

Enfim, preferências pessoais e decisões de projeto à parte, deixo abaixo uma solução com Moment.js. A vantagem é que a data é interpretada no timezone do browser, então posso manipulá-la sem medo de ter conversões implícitas de/para UTC.

Primeiro eu uso o [construtor que recebe a string e o respectivo formato](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/). Em seguida, uso [`subtract`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/) para obter o dia anterior, e por fim uso [`format`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) para retornar no formato desejado:

```js
let d = moment('2019-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
d.subtract(1, 'day');
console.log(d.format('YYYY/MM/DD')); // 2018/12/31
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

---

Repare que usei `let` em vez de `var` para declarar as variáveis. Caso tenha ficado curioso, veja [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47165/112052) para saber a diferença entre eles.

Comment: Achei a aula fantástica e não poderia deixar de aceitar sua resposta. Mas achei melhor trazer as datas direto do banco  e vou estudar mais esta tua expliação. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var date = '2019-01-01';
var d = new Date( date );
d.setDate( d.getDate() );

splite = d.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR').split("/");

dia =splite[0];
mes =splite[1];
ano =splite[2];

data = ano + "/" + mes + "/" + dia; 
document.write(data);
```