# Tratar data corretamente

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter, datetime, fullcalendar

Possuo uma agenda onde estou usando a biblioteca Fullcalendar (javascript) e quando clico em um evento desejo que mais informação deste sejam exibadas até ai tudo certo agora possuo um campo `form` em um modal retornado uma data do banco de dados mas ele retorna como vou mostrar a seguir:

Banco de dados:
[image: Banco de dados]

Como a data esta chegando no meu campo desejado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código até então:

```
eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view){
        $('#id').val(event.id);
        $('#ccod').val(event.codigoCliente);
        $('#mtitulo').val(event.title);
        $('#autor').val(event.autor);
        $('#inicioEdit').val(event.start);
        $('#importanciaEdit').val(event.impor);
        $('#descricaoEventoEdit').val(event.text);
        $('#modalEvento').modal();
      },
```

Modal:

```
<div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-md-6">
              <label for="inicio">Data</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <label for="importancia">Prioridade</label>
            </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <div class="input-group date">
              <input type="text" class="form-control date" id="inicioEdit" name="data" />
              <div class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Gostaria de uma ajuda para conseguir colocar esta data retornada no formato `'yyyy-mm-dd'`

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como formatar data no javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6526/5878)

Answer (score 0):

Podes tratar a data da seguinte maneira:

```
function dataAtualFormatada(){
var data = new Date();
var dia = data.getDate();
if (dia.toString().length == 1)
  dia = "0"+dia;
  var mes = data.getMonth()+1;
 if (mes.toString().length == 1)
  mes = "0"+mes;
  var ano = data.getFullYear();  
 return dia+"/"+mes+"/"+ano;
}
```