# Como formatar uma data por extenso?

Tags: javascript

Como converter um `Date` para a data por extenso?
Gostaria de mostrar a data de hoje no seguinte formato:

> Quinta-feira, 20 de Julho de 2017

O código de exemplo que gostaria de completar para obter o resultado acima em um `label` está exemplificado abaixo, precisando alterar a região do comentário para a lógica de obtenção da data.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'});
  $('#btnFormatar').click(formatar);
});

function formatar() {
  var data = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
  var extenso;
  
  // Lógica para formatar a data
  extenso = '*DIA DA SEMANA*, *DIA DO MÊS* de *MÊS* de *ANO*';
  console.log(data);

  $('#lblDataExtenso').html(extenso);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Data: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
<p><button id="btnFormatar">Formatar</button>
<p><label id="lblDataExtenso">???</label></p>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

Comment: Talvez este Link ajude "https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6526/como-formatar-data-no-javascript". Existe também uma biblioteca para datas que foi mencionada neste link aí: "http://momentjs.com/"

Comment: use : https://momentjs.com/ ajuda?

Comment: Seria algo assim que precisa? https://jsfiddle.net/trgva8L1/

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss exatamente

Answer (score 9, accepted):

É possível fazer de uma maneira manual, criando a lista de nomes dos dias da semana, acessando a posição [`data.getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay), e criando a lista de nomes de meses, acessando a posição [`data.getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth). O primeiro método retorna um valor `0~6` para domingo até sábado e o segundo método retorna `0~11` para Janeiro até Dezembro. O dia numérico pode ser obtido com [`data.getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) e o ano com [`data.getFullYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear). Veja um exemplo abaixo:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'});
  $('#btnFormatar').click(formatar);
});

function formatar() {
  var data = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
  var extenso;
  
  data = new Date(data);

  var day = ["Domingo", "Segunda-feira", "Terça-feira", "Quarta-feira", "Quinta-feira", "Sexta-feira", "Sábado"][data.getDay()];
  var date = data.getDate();
  var month = ["Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro"][data.getMonth()];
  var year = data.getFullYear();

  console.log(data);

  $('#lblDataExtenso').html(`${day}, ${date} de ${month} de ${year}`);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Data: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
<p><button id="btnFormatar">Formatar</button>
<p><label id="lblDataExtenso">???</label></p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Já existe a resposta para a pergunta, mas para questões de referências futuras, existe uma biblioteca muito boa para manipular tempo [momentjs](https://momentjs.com)!

```
  moment.locale('pt');
   moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // Julho 20º 2017, 11:42:53 pm
moment().format('dddd');                    // Quinta-Feira
moment().format("MMM Do YY");               // Jul 20º 17
moment().format('YYYY [escaped] YYYY');     // 2017 escaped 2017
moment().format('LLLL'); // Quinta-Feira, 20 de Julho de 2017 23:49
```

Comment: Pode confirmar se na primeira linha de código é `licale` mesmo ou seria `locale`? Não editei porque não conheço a biblioteca, então não tenho certeza sobre isso.

Comment: desculpe foi uma falha! é `locale`

Answer (score -4):

```
const option = {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: ('long' || 'short' || 'numeric'),
    weekday: ('long' || 'short'),
    day: 'numeric'
}
const locale = 'pt-br'
new Date().toLocaleDateString( locale, option)
```

// Resultado: quarta-feira, 19 de outubro de 2022

Comment: A sua solucao eh legal, mas carece de explicacoes e tem algumas propriedades definidas de forma confusa