# Qual o propósito do moment.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

Comprei um template bootstrap novo para o meu sistema, e ele veio com um negócio incluido que me devolve vários alertas, o moment.js.

Pelo que consegui entender ele é como uma biblioteca de validação client-side com suporte a idiomas e conversão de alguns formatos de data e não entendi mais nada além disso.

Exemplo:

Possuo um daterange pra gerar relatorios, e quando ativo esse daterange, o moment notifica ao meu console:

> Deprecation warning: moment().subtract(period, number) is deprecated.
>   Please use moment().subtract(number, period).

Mas o codigo funciona, e se eu corrijo isso informado warning, o daterange para de funcionar como deveria.

A dúvida é:

> Pra que realmente serve o moment.js ?
>
> O que eu posso fazer com ele ?

Obs: Pergunto isso porque eu realmente não vi utilidade nenhuma nele, e vários templates vem com ele acoplado, mas acredito que eu esteja errado acerca disso e que provavelment ele deve ser util.

Comment: O moment.js é a maior (e talvez a melhor) biblioteca para trabalhar com datas em JavaScript. Se o código deixa de funcionar quando corriges o código para a sintaxe/API que o aviso indica sugiro colocares aqui um exemplo na pergunta para ajudar-mos.

Comment: @Sergio minha dúvida não é pelo código ou algum erro, eu trato datas com PHP em meu sistema, eu quero entender o que ele é e o que da pra fazer com ele, e quem sabe passar a usar, pois não consegui entender sozinho como funciona.

Comment: A API para trabalhar com data/hora do javascript é meio limitada, a ideia do moment.js é preencher essas lacunas e tornar mais simples determinadas tarefas. Veja um [exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6526/91)

Comment: @rray consegue me passar algum link com artigo sobre ele ? os que eu li não esclareceram muita coisa, é só tutorial de como fazer coisas ou é um resumo muito simplório, pode ser em ingles sem problemas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta mensagem indica que quem criou o template usou comandos descontinuados do `moment.js`:

> Deprecation warning: moment().subtract(period, number) is deprecated. Please use moment().subtract(number, period).

O moment.js é uma lib usada para trabalhar com data e hora, a API deles permite fazer calculos e formatações de maneira mais fácil.

Se esta emitindo esses warnings então é preciso solicitar ao desenvolvedor do template que faça os ajustes necessários, ele provavelmente escreveu as primeiras versões do template usando o código conforme uma versão mais antiga do moment.js, quando ele foi fazer o upgrade do moment.js ele não notou os warnings.

Essa mensagem especifica que você citou é mencionada em https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/

> Before version 2.8.0, the moment#subtract(String, Number) syntax was also supported. It has been deprecated in favor of moment#subtract(Number, String).

Então mude o códigos semelhantes a este:

```
 moment().subtract('seconds', 1); // Deprecated in 2.8.0
```

Para algo semelhante a isto:

```
 moment().subtract(1, 'seconds');
```