# Converter string pra date

Tags: javascript

Como faço pra converter:

```
var x = "12/10/2017 12:08:26"
```

pro formato:

```
"Thu Oct 12 2017 00:00:00"
```

Alguém tem ideia?

Comment: Já tentou algo [dessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6526/5878)?

Comment: Uma das respostas sugeria a biblioteca que usei. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Com javascript puro**

O construtor new Date() com string deve ser no formato `mm-dd-yyyy` ou `mm/dd/yyyy`.

No teu caso, a data está em formato português `dd/mm/yyyy`, você precisa converter a string para o formato `mm/dd/yyyy`.

Para isso, utilizamos o método split(), que devolve um array com o valor de cada uma das partes da data, utilizando como separador o caractere "/". Porém, antes separamos a data do horário utilizando como separador o caractere espaço `" "`

```js
var x = "12/10/2017 12:08:26";

var partes = x.split(" ");

var horario = partes[1];

var partesData = partes[0].split("/");

var x = partesData[1]+"/"+partesData[0]+"/"+partesData[2];

hoje = new Date(x)
dia = hoje.getDate()
dias = hoje.getDay()
mes = hoje.getMonth()
ano = hoje.getYear()
if (dia < 10)
dia = "0" + dia
if (ano < 1000)
ano+=1900
function CriaArray (n) {
this.length = n }

NomeDia = new CriaArray(7)
NomeDia[0] = "Sun"
NomeDia[1] = "Mon"
NomeDia[2] = "Tues"
NomeDia[3] = "Wed"
NomeDia[4] = "Thurs"
NomeDia[5] = "Fri"
NomeDia[6] = "Sat"

NomeMes = new CriaArray(12)
NomeMes[0] = "Jan"
NomeMes[1] = "Feb"
NomeMes[2] = "Mar"
NomeMes[3] = "Apr"
NomeMes[4] = "May"
NomeMes[5] = "Jun"
NomeMes[6] = "Jul"
NomeMes[7] = "Aug"
NomeMes[8] = "Sep"
NomeMes[9] = "Oct"
NomeMes[10] = "Nov"
NomeMes[11] = "Dec"

console.log( NomeDia[dias] +" " + NomeMes[mes] + " " + dia + " " + ano + " " + horario);
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia!

O Javascript possui tratamento nativo as datas através da classe **Date**.

Tu podes fazer algo assim:

```js
var date = new Date("12/10/2017 12:08:26");
console.log(date.toString());
```

Comment: Agradeço sua resposta, mas não funcionou não.

Comment: O que não deu certo? O método nativo toString() retorna também o fuso da data em questão. Existem diversos tipos de formatação para buscar a data completa. Podes dar uma olhada em https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp

Comment: Não sei exatamente o motivo, mas era como se o toString() não existisse. Publiquei a solução que deu certo aqui embaixo. Obrigado!

Comment: Na realidade a solução que tu colocou em cima não foi a que responde a tua primeira pergunta. Na pergunta tu explicita um formato de data que possua o Dia da semana e o mês por extenso, coisa que tua solução não faz.

Answer (score 0):

Minha ideia era mostrar na tela no formato:

```
"12/10/2017 00:00:00"
```

Mas trabalhar no backend no formato

```
"Thu Oct 12 2017 00:00:00"
```

No caso, o que fiz pra resolver o problema foi usar uma biblioteca **moment.js**

https://momentjs.com/

A solução final ficou assim:

```
var x = new Date(this.$moment(new Date()).format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss"))
```