# Mudar formato de data em javaScript?

Tags: javascript, data

Meu formato de data ta `yyyy-mm-dd` e quero mudar pra `dd-mm-yyyy`

Eu to puxando os dados de data de uma api, ai coloquei ela com os "-" exemplo: **2017-12-31** porque antes só vinha com `20171231` mas quero mudar pra `31-12-2017`

Primeiro eu puxo o API pro meu site:

```
function load() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.open("GET", "API AQUI");

  xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
      var resposta = xhr.responseText;
      console.log("ola1");
      var clientes = JSON.parse(resposta);
      console.log("ola2");
      console.log(clientes);

      for (var i =0; i < 1; i++){
          console.log("ola3");
         var clientes_1 = clientes.TRACKER[i];
         adicionaClienteNaTabelaEntregue(clientes_1);
         console.log("ola4");
     }

  });

  xhr.send();
      }
      window.onload = load;
```

Depois eu coloco na minha table

```
    function adicionaClienteNaTabelaEntregue(cliente) {
//    var pacienteTr = montaTr(cliente);
    var clienteTr = montaTr(cliente);
    var tabela = document.querySelector("#tabela-clientes");
    tabela.appendChild(clienteTr);
}

function montaTr(cliente) {
    var clienteTr = document.createElement("tr");
    clienteTr.classList.add("cliente");

      clienteTr.appendChild(montaTd(cliente.DTAENT, "info-entconfirmada"));
      clienteTr.appendChild(montaTd(cliente.DTAMONORC, ".info-montprevista"));
      clienteTr.appendChild(montaTd(cliente.DTAMON, ".info-montconfirmada"));
      clienteTr.appendChild(montaTd(cliente.FILORC, "info-loja"));

    return clienteTr;
}

function montaTd(dado, classe) {
    var td = document.createElement("td");
    td.classList.add(classe);
    td.textContent = dado;

    return td;
}
```

E os dados da API vêm assim:

```
DTAMON:"2017-07-24"
DTAMONORC:"2017-07-12"
DTAPREENT:"2017-07-14"
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como formatar data no javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6526/como-formatar-data-no-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talvez a maneira mais rápida e talvez não muito seguro (se o formato estiver sempre nesse padrão, pode ser usado sem problemas), mas, funcional seria:

```js
var _str = '2016-03-01';
_new = _str.split('-').reverse().join('-');
console.log(_new);
```

o [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) vai quebrar esse texto em 3 partes de um `array`, o comando [reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) vai mudar a ordem onde o primeiro vai ser o ultimo o segundo o antepenúltimo e assim por diante e [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) monta novamente a data no formato desejado, juntando todas as posições com o separador informado.

---

No seu código atual crie uma função da seguinte forma:

```
function formatDate(str)
{
    return str.split('-').reverse().join('-');
}
```

e no seu código chame:

```
function montaTr(cliente) 
{
    var clienteTr = document.createElement("tr");
    clienteTr.classList.add("cliente");

    clienteTr.appendChild(montaTd(formatDate(cliente.DTAENT), "info-entconfirmada"));
    clienteTr.appendChild(montaTd(formatDate(cliente.DTAMONORC), ".info-montprevista"));
    clienteTr.appendChild(montaTd(formatDate(cliente.DTAMON), ".info-montconfirmada"));
    clienteTr.appendChild(montaTd(cliente.FILORC, "info-loja"));

    return clienteTr;
}
```

***Referencias***

- [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [Array.prototype.reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)
- [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: Mas eu não to pegando uma data certa, a data vem do api e ela pode mudar, entende?

Comment: O código dele foi só um exemplo @NazareLisboa, no lugar da primeira linha, você passa a sua data no formato que tem atualmente.

Comment: @NazareLisboa o exemplo tanto meu quanto do outro amigo que responde satisfaz de certo modo sua duvida, mas, a sua pergunta não sabemos da onde vem o dado, se poderia editar e informar isso para gente!?

Comment: Pronto. Já editei a pergunta

Comment: @NazareLisboa faz uma função e depois chame no método que monta a tabela, fiz a edição está na resposta.

Comment: Resolveu o meu problema. Muito obrigada!