# Aparecer data automaticamente ao criar formulário

Tags: php, html, mysql

**Tenho este código:**

```
 <p><h5><strong>Data de Atribuição</strong></h5> <input id="DataAtribuicao" type="text" name="DataAtribuicao" value='<?php echo date("d/m/Y"); ?>'>
```

Mas queria o mesmo mas onde o `type="date"` e aparecesse a data do dia automaticamente.

Comment: É melhor usa um javascript puro já nem todos os recursos do html5 rodam igual em diferentes navegadores isso quando funciona. [Como formatar data no javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6526/91)

Comment: Pode colocar um exemplo?

Comment: um exemplo https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu `input` esta com o `value` escrito errado.

**Tente assim no seu arquivo .php e teste no seu serve local:**

```
<input type="date" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>">
```

Comment: Funciona....Obrigado