# Converter data de DD/MM/YYYY para YYYY-MM-DD em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, data, momentjs

Estou usando um `datepicker`, que utiliza a biblioteca Moment.js.
O calendário exibe a data no formato local, `pt-BR`, assim como o valor retornado.
Quero pegar essa `string` e formatar no formato inglês (2018-03-20).

Usando o Moment eu poderia fazer assim:

```
moment('02/03/2018 00:00:00').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
```

Mas ele me lança esse aviso:

> Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized ISO format. moment construction falls back to js `Date()`, which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
>
> Arguments:
>
> ```
> [0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _useUTC: false, _l: undefined, _i: 01/01/2017 10:08:28, _f: undefined, _strict: undefined, _locale: [object Object]
> ```

Comment: Remove horas, fica somente a data

Comment: Exemplo: `moment(testDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');`

Comment: se o aviso te incomoda porque não simplesmente usar console.clear()? Se não você vai acabar caindo no problema de usar uma shotgun para matar formiga

Comment: desculpe o meu datepicker usa horas, devia ter colocado ali

Comment: @Paz porque quando faço o parse ele da o aviso e me retorna `invalid date`

Comment: @LeandroRR, não tem nada de errado, aqui funciona perfeito: http://jsfiddle.net/r42jg/2668/

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como formatar data no javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6526/como-formatar-data-no-javascript)

Comment: @CaiqueRomero seu comentário está errado, a pergunta do Leandro é sobre formatar data com a biblioteca moments.

Comment: @CaiqueRomero não é duplicata porque a pergunta que citou tá fazendo o inverso, de inglês para português.

Comment: Veja a resposta do @CaiqueRomero, e veja se resolveu o problema, não esquece de aceitar a resposta como aceita.

Comment: @LeandroRR parece-me que você esta tentando internacionalizar seu software/sistema más, o formato **YYYY-MM-DD** não é comum para os usuários de língua Inglesa (en-US) que seguem (usam) o formato **MM/DD/YYYY**. Acredito que se o objetivo é "internacionalizar" o software devas seguir o formato padrão da lingua.

Comment: @LauroMoraes o formato que estou tentando fazer o parse, é para armazenar no meu banco de dados SQL Server.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Você pode pegar a `string` e quebrar ela partes utilizando o método [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) para separar as partes utilizando `/` como parâmetro e em seguida ordenar ela no formato que desejar.

No exemplo abaixo tanto no dia quanto no mês eu concateno um zero e pego  os dois últimos elementos da sequência usando a função [slice(-2)](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) assim eu garanto que ficará com 2 dígitos imprimindo o resultado desejado.

Segue função de exemplo:

```js
function FormataStringData(data) {
  var dia  = data.split("/")[0];
  var mes  = data.split("/")[1];
  var ano  = data.split("/")[2];

  return ano + '-' + ("0"+mes).slice(-2) + '-' + ("0"+dia).slice(-2);
  // Utilizo o .slice(-2) para garantir o formato com 2 digitos.
}


console.log(FormataStringData('02/03/2018'));
```

Segue uma solução utilizando a biblioteca moment.js:

```js
/*
Você deve informar para o moment 
o formato de entrada, ou seja, como está 
a string com sua data antes de 
formatá-la pois internamente ele
fará um parse e chamará um new Date().

Fonte: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/
*/
var data = moment("02/03/2018", "DD/MM/YYYY");

//Feito isso basta definir o formato de saída:
console.log(data.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Me corrija se eu estiver errado, más  saída no formato "en-US" de `Intl.DateTimeFormat` que é usada por javascript não deveria ser: **03-02-2018** ? Do jeito que está não é o formato "en-US"

Comment: A `Intl` descreve que: o inglês americano usa **MM/DD/YYYY** uma pequena diferença (caso de uso) britânico que usa **DD/MM/YYYY**

Comment: Não pelo nome, pelo formato da saída mesmo... ao que me parece a resposta satisfaz a pergunta más, a própria pergunta parece "querer criar um formato Americano" **YYYY-MM-DD** quando na verdade o formato Americano usado por `Intl.DateTimeFormat` é **MM/DD/YYYY**

Comment: Vou sugerir isto ao autor

Answer (score 8):

Eu acredito que a resposta apresentada por [Caique Romero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/88202/caique-romero) atenda a pergunta especifica do autor más, gostaria de deixar esta resposta a modo enriquecer o tópico.

Parece-me que o autor busca internacionalizar seu software/sistema e converter uma entrada do usuário formatada localmente (pt-BR neste caso) para "en-US" contudo, o formato "sugerido" pelo autor **YYYY-MM-DD** não é o formato usual da língua inglesa (americana) que usa por padrão **MM/DD/YYYY**.

O seguinte exemplo representa a saída "correta" caso o intuito seja mesmo a internacionalização:

```js
let dateObj = new Date('02/03/2018 00:00:00')

let dateString = dateObj.toLocaleString('en-US', {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: '2-digit',
    day: '2-digit',
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute:'2-digit',
    second:'2-digit'
}).replace(/\//g, '-')

console.log(dateString)
```

Um simples `replace()` substituí as "barras" caso isto seja mesmo importante.

A de se notar que o formato de horas em "pt-BR" utiliza 24 horas enquanto o formato "en-US" apenas 12 por isso a saída sempre terá "AM" ou "PM" para indicar qual período do dia esta sendo referenciado.

A formatação da língua inglesa também difere quanto a Americanos e Britânicos, Britânicos usam o formato **DD/MM/YYYY** como neste exemplo:

```js
let dateObj = new Date('02/03/2018 00:00:00')

let dateString = dateObj.toLocaleString('en-GB', {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: '2-digit',
    day: '2-digit',
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute:'2-digit',
    second:'2-digit'
}).replace(/\//g, '-')

console.log(dateString)
```

Britânicos usam o formato de 24 horas por isso não há "AM/PM" na saída, parece com o nosso "pt-BR" a única diferença está em uma virgula após a data.

O seguinte exemplo utiliza UNIXTimeStamp obtido localmente (pt-BR) e o utiliza para converter nas saídas "en-US" e "en-GB" padrão (`replace()` para substituir as "barras")

```js
let UNIX = Date.now()

console.log('UnixTimeStamp: ', UNIX)
console.log('Unix String (UTC): ', new Date(UNIX))

function Format(timestamp, lang) {

   let dateObj = new Date(timestamp)
   
   return dateObj.toLocaleString(lang, {
       year: 'numeric',
       month: '2-digit',
       day: '2-digit',
       hour: '2-digit',
       minute:'2-digit',
       second:'2-digit'
   }).replace(/\//g, '-')
   
}

console.log('formato pt-BR: ', Format(UNIX, 'pt-BR'))
console.log('formato en-US: ', Format(UNIX, 'en-US'))
console.log('formato en-GB: ', Format(UNIX, 'en-GB'))
```

O exemplo acima apenas exibe a formatação com base no UNIX, ele não expressa a diferença entre TimeZones.

Em sistemas abertos como de postagens (blogs) é muito comum ter usuários de várias partes do mundo, ao por exemplo salvar a data já formatada da publicação de um usuário no banco, como mostrar aos outros usuários "espalhados" pelo mundo a data da postagem (de maneira fluida em seus idiomas e horários)? Salvando a data da publicação em UNIXTimeStamp isto é possível:

```js
let UNIX = Date.now()

console.log('UnixTimeStamp: ', UNIX)
console.log('Unix String (UTC): ', new Date(UNIX))

function Format(timestamp, lang, tz) {

   let dateObj = new Date(timestamp)
   
   return dateObj.toLocaleString(lang, {
       timeZone: tz,
       year: 'numeric',
       month: '2-digit',
       day: '2-digit',
       hour: '2-digit',
       minute:'2-digit',
       second:'2-digit'
   }).replace(/\//g, '-')
   
}

console.log('formato pt-BR: ', Format(UNIX, 'pt-BR','America/Sao_Paulo'))
console.log('formato en-US: ', Format(UNIX, 'en-US', 'America/New_York'))
console.log('formato en-GB: ', Format(UNIX, 'en-GB', 'Europe/London'))
```

O exemplo acima usa a opção **timeZone** de `toLocaleString()` para simular o timezone local de possíveis usuários ao redor do mundo, neste caso, um Paulista um "Novayorkino" e um Londrino.

Como os países podem ter mais de um timezone em um ambiente real o correto seria pegar o timezone local do usário (que esta vendo/acessando uma publicação):

```js
console.log(Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone)
```

Deste modo usuários "espalhados" pelo mundo podem ver data exata de quando outro usuário fez uma publicação levando em consideração seu horário local.

---

**NOTA:**

> A melhor maneira de trabalhar com datas para formatação (internacionalização) é usar referencias UNIXTimeStamp pois podem ser formatadas pra qualquer saída. Ao usar strings já formatadas você terá problemas em converter (formatar) para outras saídas.

---

**Referencias**

UnixTimeStamp: [RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14), [ISO8601 seção 15.9.1.15](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15)

JavaScript objeto `Date()`: [Mozila Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

JavaScript `Intl.DateTimeFormat()`: [Mozila Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat)

JavaScript `toLocaleString()`: [Mozila Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

Tags de idioma usadas em `toLocaleString()` seguem o [BCP47](http://www.rfc-editor.org/bcp/bcp47.txt)

Complemetos:

- post: [JavaScript Internationalization API](http://marcoscaceres.github.io/jsi18n/)

Answer (score 3):

Acho que vale mencionar alguns detalhes que as outras respostas não cobriram, ou apenas o fizeram de maneira superficial.

## O motivo do *warning*

O aviso "*value provided is not in a recognized ISO format*" ocorre porque, [segundo a documentação](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/), ao criar um `moment` passando-se somente uma string contendo a data, primeiro é verificado se ela representa uma data no formato [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (que no caso seria `2018-03-02T00:00:00`). Caso não esteja, ele verifica se o formato está de acordo com a [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.3) (que seria algo como `02 Mar 2018 00:00:00 -0300`). E se não estiver em nenhum desses formatos, é feito o *fallback* para `Date`: no caso, ele chama `new Date(string)`.

Só que, conforme explicado [aqui](/a/408168/112052), a [especificação da linguagem](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) diz que o único formato garantido que funciona em todos os ambientes é o ISO 8601. Qualquer outra coisa é dependente da implementação, e pode ou não funcionar dependendo do ambiente (seja um *browser*, ou Node, [Deno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deno), etc).

**É isso que o *warning* está dizendo**: a string está em um formato que não é ISO 8601 nem RFC 2822 ("dia/mês/ano hora:minuto:segundo"), por isso a string é passada para o construtor de `Date`, e aí pode ou não funcionar (*is not reliable across all browsers and versions*).

Por exemplo, criando a data com `new Date('02/03/2018 00:00:00')`, o resultado foi **3 de fevereiro** em vez de 2 de março (testei no Node, Chrome e Firefox). Aliás, com `moment` também dá o mesmo resultado, já que ele acaba chamando `new Date`, como já explicado. Veja que o resultado abaixo é `2018-02-03 00:00:00` (3 de fevereiro), além, é claro, de mostrar o *warning*:

```js
// 2018-02-03 00:00:00
console.log(moment('02/03/2018 00:00:00').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

A solução para isso já foi dada em [uma das respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/445228/112052): basta informar ao `moment` qual o formato da string. Assim ele cria a data correta e não mostra mais o *warning*:

```js
// 2018-03-02 00:00:00
console.log(moment('02/03/2018 00:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
//                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                                         formato no qual a string está
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Passando o formato, o `moment` não faz mais o *fallback* para `new Date` e interpreta corretamente a string, gerando a data correta (no exemplo acima, `2018-03-02 00:00:00` - 2 de março). E o *warning* não aparece mais.

---

Vale lembrar também que o formato YYYY-MM-DD **não** é o formato americano. Na verdade, nos EUA costuma-se usar MM/DD/YYYY (ou ainda "Mar 2<sup>nd</sup>, 2018"). O formato YYYY-MM-DD é o ISO 8601.

> Na verdade, sendo bem pedante, quando tem data e hora, o formato ISO 8601 diz que deve ter a letra "T" maiúscula entre a data e a hora, portanto ficaria `2018-03-02T00:00:00`. Já o formato que você quer tem um espaço em vez do "T", e este formato é definido pela [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) (que é um *profile* da ISO 8601 e permite [algumas dessas diferenças](https://stackoverflow.com/q/522251)).

Enfim, com `moment` a ideia geral é essa: ao criar a data, você passa a string e o formato no qual ela está. Ao formatá-la, você informa o formato para o qual ela deve ser convertida.

Quanto a usar JavaScript puro, infelizmente o `Date` não dá muitas opções e o jeito é tratar a string manualmente, como as outras respostas fizeram. Apenas para deixar registrada mais uma alternativa (meio "feia", mas sinceramente, todas são, já que a linguagem não dá muitas opções nativas para lidar com datas):

```js
const str = '02/03/2018 00:00:00';
let [dia, mes, ano, hora, minuto, segundo] = str.split(/[\/ :]/).map(v => parseInt(v));
const data = new Date(Date.UTC(ano, mes - 1, dia, hora, minuto, segundo));
console.log(data.toISOString().replace('T', ' ').substring(0, 19));
```

`toISOString()` retorna a data no formato ISO 8601, então basta trocar o "T" por espaço e eliminar as frações de segundo. Só que tem outro detalhe: este método retorna a data/hora em UTC (e não no fuso horário configurado no browser, como acontece com outros métodos como `toLocaleString()`), por isso criei a data com `Date.UTC`. Também precisei subtrair 1 do mês, já que [no JavaScript janeiro é zero, fevereiro é 1, etc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405998/112052).

Answer (score 2):

**Usando JS puro (sem momentjs):**

```js
let date = "02/03/2018 00:00:00";
// Divido a string pelo único espaço que tem, depois divido o primeiro item do array pela barra '/', reverto a string e, finalmente, junto todos os itens da matriz com um hífen.
date = date.split(" ")[0].split("/").reverse().join('-');
console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

É simples!

```
moment('08/04/2018 00:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss', true).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function formata_data(data) { // dd/mm/yyyy -> yyyy-mm-dd
    data_formatada = data.substr(6,4) + '-' + data.substr(3,2) + '-' + data.substr(0,2) + ' 00:00:00';
    return new Date(data_formatada);
}
```

Comment: Essa resposta não é valida para questão levantada pois o objeto da questão é a biblioteca `moment.js` e não o tipo nativo `Date`.