# Como mostrar o objeto Date com o timezone que ele foi criado em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, data, timezone

Estou com a seguinte dúvida, quando crio um objeto `Date` com a seguinte string:

```
var teste = new Date("2020-06-03T12:05:03-05:00");
```

Dessa forma  criei um objeto `Date` que diz que são `12:05:03` com um *offset* de -5 horas do horário UTC (nesse caso o horário em UTC seria `17:05:03`).

Ou seja, o objeto foi **criado** usando um timezone que é de **-5 horas**. Porém, meu computador está com o timezone **-3 horas** (BRT). Com isso quando tento exibir o objeto `teste` que criei, ele exibe dessa forma:

```
console.log(teste.toString()); // Wed Jun 03 2020 14:05:03 GMT-0300 (-03)
```

Ou seja, ele formata a exibição para o timezone do meu navegador.

Gostaria de saber se há alguma forma de fazer ele exibir esta data, com o timezone que foi informado na criação do objeto (-5 horas), sem precisar alterar o timezone do meu computador, algo semelhante a isto:

```
console.log(teste.algumMetodo()); // Wed Jun 03 2020 12:05:03 GMT-0500 (-05)
```

Ou seja, que mantenha o timezone em que o objeto foi criado.

Comment: Talvez seja melhor começar a armazenar suas datas em UNIXTimestamp assim poderá usar bibliotecas como **moment.js** ou mesmo as API's nativas. Dê uma olhada nesta resposta talvez lhe ajude a compreender melhor: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/285238#285388 **PS**: sempre salve o timestamp capturado no servidor

Comment: Bem-vindo ao maravilhoso mundo caótico do tratamento de datas no Javascript. O js tem muitas coisas boas mas certamente o tratamento de datas não é um deles. É um verdadeiro caos. Como alguém que já passou muitas horas batendo a cabeça com os Dates e Timezones do Javascript lhe aconselho: nem perca seu tempo, use logo o moment.js ou será forçado a usar depois de muito se bater.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O [`Date` do JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) **não** guarda a informação do timezone. Apesar do nome, o `Date` não é bem uma data (no sentido de representar um único valor de dia, mês, ano, hora, minuto e segundo).

## Como assim?

Na verdade, o `Date` representa um [timestamp](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/112052): a quantidade de milissegundos decorrida desde o [*Unix Epoch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (que por sua vez equivale a `1970-01-01T00:00Z` - 1 de janeiro de 1970 à meia-noite, em [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC)).

Quando você passa uma string como `'2020-06-03T12:05:03-05:00'`, ele cria um `Date` cujo timestamp equivale a esta data, hora e *offset*. Mas ao **exibir** esta data (com `toString()`, por exemplo), ela é convertida para o fuso horário do browser.

Tanto que se você criar instâncias de `Date` com strings diferentes, mas que correspondem ao mesmo instante, verá que o valor do timestamp será o mesmo:

```js
var d1 = new Date("2020-06-03T12:05:03-05:00");
var d2 = new Date("2020-06-03T13:05:03-04:00");
console.log(d1.getTime(), d2.getTime()); // 1591203903000 1591203903000 
console.log(d1);
console.log(d2);
```

As duas datas acima possuem o mesmo valor do timestamp, e portanto correspondem ao mesmo instante. O fato de terem sido geradas com strings diferentes é um detalhe, já que as strings foram usadas para calcular o valor do timestamp, mas a informação do timezone não fica guardada no `Date` (somente o valor do timestamp).

Ao imprimi-las, o timestamp é convertido para o fuso horário do browser, e a saída é a mesma para ambas.

---

Outro ponto é que na verdade o valor `-05:00` é um [*offset*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) (a diferença com relação a UTC), e não um timezone de fato ([veja aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) para saber mais).

[Timezones](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) possuem identificadores como `America/Sao_Paulo` e `Asia/Tokyo`, e eles na verdade possuem um histórico de *offsets* usados ao longo da história, em uma determinada região. Por exemplo, `America/Sao_Paulo` [corresponde ao Horário de Brasília](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/259120/112052), e geralmente usa o *offset* `-03:00`, mas durante o horário de verão muda para `-02:00`. Esse histórico todo faz parte do timezone (quando cada *offset* é usado, quando ocorrem as transições, etc), e o *offset* pode variar de acordo com a data que você tem (se naquele instante estava em horário de verão ou não).

Então para que a saída tenha o *offset* `-05:00`, você precisaria saber qual timezone possui este *offset* naquele instante específico (e [existe mais de um](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets#UTC%E2%88%9205:00,_R) inclusive, e isso varia conforme a data e hora, já que esses timezones também podem ter horário de verão e usar outro *offset* dependendo da época).

Uma alternativa é usar [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) passando um timezone e a [opção `timeZoneName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat#timezonename), que indica o formato no qual o timezone/*offset* deve estar:

```js
var data = new Date("2020-06-03T12:05:03-05:00");
console.log(data.toLocaleString('pt-BR', { timeZoneName: 'longOffset', timeZone: 'America/Rio_Branco' }));
```

Testando no Chrome, o *offset* aparece como "GMT-05:00" (5 horas atrás do UTC), mas nada impede que implementações diferentes retornem outros formatos (a própria [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat#timezonename) dá um exemplo sem os dois-pontos: "GMT-0800").

Outro problema é que o formato da data e hora depende do *locale* informado (no caso, usei `pt-BR` - português do Brasil, que usa "dia/mês/ano hora:minuto:segundo"). Infelizmente o JavaScript não fornece muito mais recursos para manipular a data da forma que você precisa.

---

Uma alternativa é usar o [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), juntamente com o [Moment timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/). Mesmo assim precisamos passar algum timezone cujo *offset* seja `-05:00` na data em questão.

```js
let data = moment.tz("2020-06-03T12:05:03-05:00", "America/Chicago");
console.log(data.format()); // 2020-06-03T12:05:03-05:00
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Mas também há um modo de preservar o timezone passado, usando [`parseZone`](https://momentjs.com//docs/#/parsing/parse-zone/):

```js
let data = moment.parseZone("2020-06-03T12:05:03-05:00");
console.log(data.format()); // 2020-06-03T12:05:03-05:00
// outro formato
console.log(data.format('ddd, MMM DD YYYY, HH:mm:ss Z')); // Wed, Jun 03 2020, 12:05:03 -05:00

// converter para Date
let d = data.toDate();
console.log(d); // não preserva mais o -05:00, pois Date não guarda o timezone
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

---

## Gambiarra que você provavelmente vai ver por aí

Antes que alguém sugira a gambiarra, eu mesmo vou mostrar e explicar porque não é uma boa ideia:

```js
function converter(data, offset) {
    data.setTime(data.getTime() + offset * 3600 * 1000);
    let s = offset < 0 ? "-" : "+";
    return data.toISOString().slice(0, -1) + s + Math.abs(offset).toString().padStart(2, '0') + ":00";
}

var d1 = new Date("2020-06-03T12:05:03-05:00");
console.log(converter(d1, -5)); // 2020-06-03T12:05:03.000-05:00
```

Apesar de parecer uma boa ideia ("*funcionou, mostrou a data e hora correta!*"), não é, porque ao usar [`setTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setTime) estamos mudando o valor do timestamp, e a data passa a representar um instante diferente.

É como se meu computador estivesse configurado com o fuso horário de Londres (mas estou no Brasil). Aqui são 15h, mas em Londres são 19h ([os ingleses estão em horário de verão](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/uk/london?year=2020)). Então o relógio do computador mostra 19h.

Eu posso corrigir do jeito certo (mudando as configurações de fuso horário do computador), ou eu posso fazer a gambiarra e atrasar meu relógio em 4 horas: ele mostrará o valor "correto" (15h), mas na verdade eu mudei o valor que ele representa (agora ele indica que são 15h em Londres, um instante 4 horas no passado).

É isso que eu faço ao mudar o valor da data: ela passa a representar um instante diferente e dependendo do que você precisa fazer com ela, dará resultados errados (só porque ela mostra o valor "correto", não quer dizer que esteja tudo certo).

---

Veja mais sobre datas [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/344030/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/456089/112052).

Comment: Entendi, agora faz sentido o porquê, de não ser possível representar a data da forma que eu queria. Realmente essa forma de gambiarra não é interessante pra mim, visto que eu apenas preciso dessa formatação para exibir em uma página, e não gostaria de alterar, de fato, o instante que o Date representa. Vou dar uma estudada no Moment.js, já que ele consegue manter a integridade do timestamp, pode ser isso que estou procurando mesmo. Obrigado.