# Moment - problema com TimeZone

Tags: react-native, momentjs

Recebo a data do serviço da seguinte forma:

```
2020-11-05T06:15:00.000-03:00
```

Para exibir ao usuário utilizamos a biblioteca [moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-moment).

Exemplo:

```
import React from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';

var chegada = '2020-11-05T06:15:00.000-03:00';
console.log('--> data: ' + chegada);
console.log('--> data (moment):' + moment(chegada).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'));
```

Meu problema é que ele leva em consideração do *TimeZone* do smartphone.

Mudando o *TimeZone* para -04:00 tenho o seguinte resultado:

**Saída**

```
 LOG  --> data: 2020-11-05T06:15:00.000-03:00
 LOG  --> data (moment):05/11/2020 05:15
```

Como faço para levar em consideração o Timezone informado na data, e não do smartphone?

Comment: @hkotsubo é uma boa resposta, mas acho que ele quer saber como faz isso usando o *momentjs* e não JavaScript puro.

Comment: Thiago teste a minha resposta vê se no react-native fica igual a data passada por favor?

Comment: @CmteCardeal Se vc ler a resposta que tem na duplicada que sugeri, vai ver que lá também tem uma opção de solução com Moment.js, e que - pelo que entendi - serve para o caso em questão (`moment.parseZone`)

Comment: @hkotsubo tem mesmo ... só precisamos saber se no aparelho vai funcionar mas, ta certinho.

Comment: @hkotsubo, sim! responde perfeitamente!

Comment: Aliás o @novic também deu uma solução simples e com o mesmo resultado que a pergunta sugerida! Muito Obrigado a Todos!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na documentação tem que chamar o método [parseZone(false)](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/local/) para [react-native](/questions/tagged/react-native):

---

```js
const chegada = '2020-11-03T06:15:00.000-03:00';
const formatada = moment
  .parseZone(chegada)
  .format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');

document.getElementById('chegada').innerHTML = chegada;
document.getElementById('formatada').innerHTML = formatada;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment-with-locales.min.js" integrity="sha512-LGXaggshOkD/at6PFNcp2V2unf9LzFq6LE+sChH7ceMTDP0g2kn6Vxwgg7wkPP7AAtX+lmPqPdxB47A0Nz0cMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div>
  <div id="chegada"></div>
  <div id="formatada"></div>
</div>
```

Outra forma também que funciona:

```
moment('2020-11-05T06:15:00.000-03:00')
        .utcOffset(-3)
        .format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm')
```

---

<sup>***Referencia do site:*** [Como mostrar o objeto Date com o timezone que ele foi criado em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/455437/como-mostrar-o-objeto-date-com-o-timezone-que-ele-foi-criado-em-javascript)</sup>

Comment: Nesse caso, ele teria que extrair o timezone da string pra passar como argumento no `utcOffset`? Porque estou assimindo que o timezone vai ser dinâmico e de acordo com a data do serviço.

Comment: Então @CmteCardeal não sei? eu li na documentação e crie a resposta, seria realmente um código pouco eficiente se tiver esse fator dinâmico ! Ele me perguntou do Timezone que é depreciado e tem que usar `utcOffset`...

Comment: @CmteCardeal eu coloquei outro método e vou deixar ele testar!

Comment: @novic, perfeito! funcionou !!! Uma outra maneira que descobri seria : moment.parseZone(chegada).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm')

Comment: @ThiagoLuizDomacoski Só pra constar, usar `local` pode não dar o resultado desejado em todos os casos, pois ele varia conforme o timezone configurado no ambiente no qual o código roda (seja o browser, o node, etc). [Veja aqui](https://repl.it/repls/WearyLinedPacket#index.js) um exemplo que dá diferença (e veja que com `parseZone` não dá essa diferença)

Comment: No caso dele é no aparelho e isso eu testei e funciona @hkotsubo é react-native o caso em especifico.

Comment: @novic Bom, como eu não conheço muito bem react-native, vou acreditar em vc :-) Só quis alertar para o caso mais geral (browsers, etc), já que lidar com timezones sempre tem dessas "armadilhas", no JavaScript então nem se fala...

Comment: Bom eu testei no expo @hkotsubo mas, para sanar essa duvida vou colocar só o parseZone então ...

Comment: Acho que pode deixar o `local` também, só acrescentando a ressalva talvez (caso ela se aplique ao react, senão deixa assim mesmo)

Comment: vou deixar o padrão da sua resposta acho melhor @hkotsubo ...