# Como eu posso executar uma função somente uma vez em um período de tempo

Tags: javascript, array, loop, for, agendamento

### Queria saber como posso fazer uma execução única, exemplo:

Na minha aplicação há a uma forma de agendar cobranças e elas são
agendadas por dia, então em um certo dia **X** ela será cobrada.

---

Atualmente estou fazendo dessa forma:

```
const da = Number(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('pt-br', { day: '2-digit' }).format(new Date(Date.now())));

let arr = [
  { name: "Salário", amount: 150000, day: 5 },
  { name: "Internet", amount: -11590, day: 10 },
  { name: "Teste", amount: 15000, day: 5 },
];

const indexofday = arr.reduce((acc, obj, index) => {
  if (obj.day === da) {
    acc.push(index);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

const newarr = indexofday.map((item) => Array[item]);

//Função para adicionar essa array em outro local da aplicação. O concat e somente um exemplo!

newarr.forEach((transaction, index) => {
  datastorage.concat(transaction, index);
});
```

Essa função é que eu estou usando atualmente, porém quando eu atualizo a página e o dia continua o mesmo, é executado essa função novamente! Isso cria uma *loop* na minha aplicação. Há alguma forma de executar isso somente uma vez ao dia?

Comment: Desconheco outra forma além não usar algum armazenamento do navegador e persistir algum dado para ser verificado antes de executar a funcao, pois ao recarregar a página, todo JS vai ser executado novamente. Vou esperar pra ver alguem propôr alguma solução criativa.... ou não.... ou dizer que estou errado :).

Comment: Vale lembrar que não precisa obter os índices para depois acessar, através de indexação, os respectivos elementos. Você pode fazer isso numa única “redução”.

Comment: Isso é interessante, bom saber muito obrigada! Vou fazer direto da próxima vez!

Comment: @Ellathet, vc quer dizer uma vez ao dia (independente do horário, a cada ciclo de 24hs) para algo que tem um ciclo mensal (a cada **x** dia do mês)...o que vêm a mente seria um **cookie**. Ao executar a função verifica se existe um **cookie**, se não existir (primeira vez) cria um. Podes usar timestamp como valor e 30 dias como expiração, se existir compara seu valor (timestamp)...se passou de 24hs executa a função novamente e salva um novo **cookie** com o atual timestap, se não passou use `return` para sair da função sem fazer nada. A cada 30 dias o **cookie** é excluído e um novo criado.

Comment: @LauroMoraes, entendi, eu não entendi muito bem sem algum exemplo, nunca usei essa função de cookies. Vou pesquisar, se puder me ajudar me mandando um exemplo do `timestamp`, agradeço!

Comment: @Ellathet, publiquei um exemplo como resposta. tente adequá-lo as suas necessidades

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seguindo a lógica que você pretende aplicar:

- o script deve ser executado uma vez a cada período de 24Hs
- sua função verifica se o atual dia é igual ao dia de cobrança (mensal)
- se for igual executa

Acredito que devas mover seu código para uma função que verifique um indicador de tempo e faça a seguinte comparação:

- **1**: chegar se indicador existe, caso não exista. Criar um e chamar a função
- **2**: caso exista o indicador, verificar se é maior que o atual período (24Hs)
- **3**: caso o período seja maior, define um novo indicador e executa a função
- **4**: caso o período seja menor, não executa a função e nem ajusta o atual indicador

Não posso afirmar que seja a melhor indicação mas, usar um `Timestamp` como indicador permitiria fazer esta checagem no "front-end".

Existem "n" modos de armazenar este indicador no "front-end", aqui estou usando `document.cookie` e tomando a liberdade de modificar o dia de seu primeiro objeto de cobrança para o atual dia assim poderás ver que o `cookie` é criado e a função é chamada apenas uma vez ... elá só será chamada novamente depois de 24Hs.

**NOTA**: ocultei a saída de `console` do snippet abaixo porque ele é executado em um `<iframe>` e não pode salvar `cookies` por questões de segurança.

```js
// defina um nome mais apropriado
const SuaFunção = function() {
    // millisegundos de 24Hs
    const DayInMilliseconds = (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
    // cookie search
    const search = name => {
        return document.cookie.replace(new RegExp("(?:(?:^|.*;)\\s*" + name.replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=\\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$"), "$1") || false
    }
    // função que retorna a data de expiração do cookie (formato GMT)
    const makeTime = t => {
        if ( typeof t === 'number' ) {
            let d = new Date()
            d.setMilliseconds(d.getMilliseconds() + t * DayInMilliseconds)
            return d.toString()
        }
    }
    //
    const paymentFn = () => {
        const da = Number(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('pt-br', { day: '2-digit' }).format(new Date(Date.now())));

        let arr = [
          { name: "Salário", amount: 150000, day: da },
          { name: "Internet", amount: -11590, day: 10 },
          { name: "Teste", amount: 15000, day: 5 },
        ];

        const indexofday = arr.reduce((acc, obj, index) => {
          if (obj.day === da) {
            acc.push(index);
          }
          return acc;
        }, []);

        const newarr = indexofday.map((item) => Array[item]);

        //Função para adicionar essa array em outro local da aplicação. O concat e somente um exemplo!

        newarr.forEach((transaction, index) => {
          //datastorage.concat(transaction, index);
          console.log(transaction, index)
        });
    }

    // procura seu cookie (exemplo: "payment")
    const PaymentCookie = search('payment'),
        // pega o Timestamp atual
        TSNow = Date.now()
    if ( PaymentCookie ) {
        /*
           verifica se o Timestamp do cookie + um periodo de 24Hs (em millisegundos) é maior que o atual Timestamp
           o que significa que ainda não se passaram 24Hs
         */ 
        if ( Number(PaymentCookie) + DayInMilliseconds > TSNow ) {
            // o Timestamp do cookie ainda não passou de 24Hs
            console.log('Ainda não passaram mais de 24Hs')
            // retorna sem fazer nada, não invoca sua função de cobrança
            return
        }
        // o Timestamp do cookie já passou de 24Hs
        console.log('Já passaram mais de 24Hs')
        // caso a instrução acima não execute (por já ter passado de 24Hs) cria um novo cookie
        document.cookie = `payment=${TSNow}; expires=${makeTime(30)}`
        // executa sua função
        paymentFn()
    } else {
        // primeira execução
        console.log('Não há cookie, vamos criar um')
        // cria novo cookie com o atual Timestamp e executa sua função (expira em 30 dias)
        document.cookie = `payment=${TSNow}; expires=${makeTime(30)}`
        // chama sua função
        paymentFn()
    }
}

// chama a função em qualquer parte do script principal
SuaFunção()
```

---

**Fontes**:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Greater_than

---

**Leitura adicional**:

https://hkotsubo.github.io/blog/2019-05-02/o-que-e-timestamp

[Converter data de DD/MM/YYYY para YYYY-MM-DD em Javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/285238/converter-data-de-dd-mm-yyyy-para-yyyy-mm-dd-em-javascript/285388#285388)

Comment: Consegui usar essa forma aqui, porém ela está na função inteira, então quando eu adiciono um item nesse `arr` ele não atualiza porque o comando ainda está no timestamps, como eu iria fazer isso de uma forma que ele verifique por item no array, teria que criar uma propriedade no objeto dentro do array tem teria esse `expire`?

Comment: Se é que entendi, vc pode mover seu `Array` para fora da função ... Na função apenas chama ele  era isso?

Comment: Na verdade esse `Array` é um `localStorage` do  navegador, a questão é que já que a função é executada somente uma vez, se eu adicionar mais algumas coisas nesse `localStorage` ele não executar pois tem o período  de tempo, teria que ter um período de tempo para cada item do `array`?

Comment: @Ellathet, na vdd não. Se este `Array` esta em `localStorage` vc pode manipulá-lo em qualquer lugar de seu script não necessariamente dentro da função. Dentro da função vc só verifica e chama este `Array` e sempre terá na função os dados atualizados mesmo que vc faça mudanças fora dela. Ex: `let arr = localStorage['nome_do_objeto'] ? localStorage['nome_do_objeto'] : [];` ... assim se tiver feeito mudanças fora, terá os dados atuais quando invocar a função.

Comment: então o problema que eu estou tendo é que nesse `array/localStorage` é adicionado mais transações automáticas, então exemplo: Ele executa essa função, se eu quiser adicionar outra coisa na array ela não atualiza porqu o cookie trava a função toda!

Comment: Eu acredito que o `cookie` esteja fazendo o que ele foi proposto a fazer: executar a função apenas a cada 24Hs...como disse no comentário acima vc pode atualizar seu `Array` fora da função, na função busca seu `Array` em `localStorage` para ter as atualizações de cobrança. Se não era isso acredito que devas tentar editar sua pergunta complementando-a com o que falta e clarificando um pouco mais. Talvez assim eu possa entender melhor e alterar minha resposta ou alguém apresente uma resposta mais próximo do que buscas.

Comment: Eu dei uma olhada em seu [git](https://github.com/Ellathet/control.finance) se eu puder lhe mando um Pull request

Comment: @LauroMoreas, eu iria agradecer! Se tiver algo explicando eu queria mesmo aprender, mas aceito essa ajuda sim!