# Conversão de data no Horário de Verão

Tags: javascript

Atualmente no meu sistema eu utilizo o seguinte código, para converter as datas vindas no ajax.
`new Date(parseInt(data.replace(/\/Date\((-?\d+)\)\//, '$1')))`

Sendo que a variável `data` é uma string que vem no formato `'/Date(1508551200000)/'`, sendo assim você pode substituir a variável por essa string para testar.

Agora meu problema começou a surgir nesta data, pois quando converto ela com o código acima dá o seguinte resultado:

> Fri Oct 20 2017 23:00:00 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil)

Porém o valor real é **21/10/2017**, ao fazer uma pesquisas descobrir que essa data foi o início do horário de verão de 2017 e com isso ele diminuiu em 1hr, com isso verifiquei que as datas no horário de verão estão tendo esse mesmo problema

Como posso fazer essa conversão para q ele ignore isso e me retorne o valor q eu desejo, sem diminuir em 1hr, no caso ignorando essa conversão do horário de verão.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como formatar data no javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6526/como-formatar-data-no-javascript)

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam Eu acho que o problema não é com formatar, o autor esta com problema com o fuso-horário.

Answer (score 2):

Use o método `toLocaleString()` e em seguida converter o resultado em objeto Date:

```js
var data = '/Date(1508551200000)/';
data = new Date(parseInt(data.replace(/\/Date\((-?\d+)\)\//, '$1'))).toLocaleString('pt-BR', { timeZone: 'America/Sao_Paulo' });
var dt = data.substring(0, 10).split("/");
data = new Date(dt[2], dt[1] - 1, dt[0]);

console.log(data);
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6pj8qstw/)** => *Sat Oct 21 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil)*

Comment: Não teria como me dá o resultado no objeto Date, em vez de já está formatado?

Comment: Além disso não posso `.toLocaleString()`, dá maneira que foi passada, pois se a pessoa acessar o sistema em outro fuso vai exibir informações divergentes

Comment: Vou ver aqui... mas no caso, seria acrescentar .toLocaleString("pt-BR")

Comment: no caso só isso não seria o suficiente, teria que setar o timezone tb, por exemplo `.toLocaleString('pt-BR', { timeZone: 'America/Sao_Paulo' });`

Comment: Está certo. Veja agora.