# Como formatar data de dd/mm/yyyy para mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: javascript

Estou recebendo essa data numa variável:

```
var data = "23/03/2012 00:00:00"
```

Preciso colocar essa data em um input type date. Quando tento, aparece a mensagem falando que preciso passar através do formato (yyyy-mm-dd)

Achei essa função que formata data:

```
function formatarData(data) {

            var d = new Date(data),
                mes = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
                dia = '' + d.getDate(),
                ano = d.getFullYear();

            if (mes.length < 2) mes = '0' + mes;
            if (dia.length < 2) dia = '0' + dia;

            return [ano, mes, dia].join('-');
        }
```

Porém, quando tento executar a função com a data que estou recebendo, ele retorna (NaN-NaN-NaN).

Pesquisei aqui na internet, e vi que não pode passar data no formato (dd/mm/yyyy) no new Date.

Ai preciso formatar minha data dd/mm/yyyy para mm/dd/yyyy. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como formatar data no javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6526/como-formatar-data-no-javascript)

Comment: A outra pergunta ou resposta não funcionou?

Comment: Não, pois lá está utilizando new Date antes de formatar a data, formatos de datas diferentes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar um `substr` simples como mostrado abaixo.

```
var data = "23/03/2012 00:00:00",
    dateBlock = data.substr(6,4)+"-"+data.substr(3,2)+"-"+data.substr(0,2),
    hourBlock=data.substr(11),
    dateObj=new Date(dateBlock+" "+hourBlock);

document.body.innerHTML = "Objeto Data: "+dateObj;
document.body.innerHTML += "<br>Data: "+dateBlock;
document.body.innerHTML += "<br>Hora: "+hourBlock;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cggy9zx7/6/

Answer (score 2):

Seguindo esse padrão de data, você pode utilizar:

```
function formatarData(data) {

    // da "split" no 'espaço'
    var d = data.split(" ")[0]; // recupera 23/03/2012
    var h = data.split(" ")[1]; // recupera 00:00:00

    var dsplit = d.split("/"); // recupera o array(23, 03, 2012);
    var hsplit = h.split(":"); // recupera o array(00, 00, 00);

    // cria o objeto date
    var novaData = new Date(dsplit[2], dsplit[1] - 1, dsplit[0], hsplit[0], hsplit[1], hsplit[2]);

    // retorna o objeto date
    return novaData;

}
```

Você pode obter mais informações [sobre o split aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp).

Comment: Quando tento usar essa function aparece "data.split is not a function"

Comment: Experimenta `data.toString().split`. Provavelmente o JavaScript está interpretando essa variável como outro tipo. É necessário ser uma String para usar essa função.