# Função JavaScript não funciona

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo esta função:

```js
function toDate(data) {
  let partes = data.split('/');
  return new Date(partes[2], partes[1] - 1, partes[0]);
}
var atual_data1 = toDate($("#txtDataInicio").val());
$("#txtVencimentoC").val() = (atual_data1.format("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
var tol = ($("#txtTolerancia").val());
atual_data1.setDate(atual_data1.getDate() + parseInt(tol));
$("#txtDataTolerancia").val(atual_data1.format("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Porém ele me retorna o seguinte erro:

> ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Nesta linha:

```
$("#txtVencimentoC").val() = (atual_data1.format("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
```

Já tentei fazer assim também porém não deu certo:

```
$("#txtVencimentoC").val(atual_data1.format("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
```

Comment: Acredito que se mudar: `$("#txtVencimentoC").val() = (atual_data1.format("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));` para `$("#txtVencimentoC").val((atual_data1.format("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")));` lembre que `val()` é para settar um valor e não receber com o operador de atribuição (`=`)

Comment: seu problema https://stackoverflow.com/a/9132972/2740371

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: atual_data1.format is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) do jQuery é um método, sendo assim você precisa tratá-lo diferentemente de uma variável (que armazena um valor e é possível alterá-la com a sintaxe que você utilizou). Para setar o valor de dentro de um elemento com esse método utilize:

```
$("#txtVencimentoC").val(atual_data1.format("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
```

Outra questão é que não existe o método `format` em objetos `Date` em Javascript. Para formatar a data do mesmo modo que você descreveu, use a função nativa `toLocaleString()`:

```
$("#txtVencimentoC").val(atual_data1.toLocaleString());
```

Caso você precise de algo mais específico ou de outro tipo de formatação, dê uma olhada nas [respostas desta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6526/como-formatar-data-no-javascript).

Veja as correções no seu código:

```js
function toDate(data) {
  let partes = data.split('/');
  return new Date(partes[2], partes[1] - 1, partes[0]);
}

var atual_data1 = toDate($("#txtDataInicio").val());

$("#txtVencimentoC").val(atual_data1.toLocaleString());

var tol = $("#txtTolerancia").val();

atual_data1.setDate(atual_data1.getDate() + parseInt(tol));

$("#txtDataTolerancia").val(atual_data1.toLocaleString());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Data Inicio: <input type="text" id="txtDataInicio" value="04/07/2013"><br>
VencimentoC: <input type="text" id="txtVencimentoC"><br>
Tolerancia: <input type="text" id="txtTolerancia" value="1"><br>
Data Tolerancia: <input type="text" id="txtDataTolerancia"><br>
```

Comment: Eu tentei desta forma, me retorna outro erro: Uncaught TypeError: atual_data1.format is not a function

Comment: Alterei a resposta!

Comment: Deu certinho, obrigado.