# Clicar no botão e mostar só data e hora

Tags: javascript

Tenho este botão para dar inicio da tarefa:

```js
$('#IniciarTarefa').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('.form-group').data('inicio', new Date().getTime());
});

$('#mostrar').on('click', function () {
    var time = $('.form-group').data('inicio');
    alert(new Date(time));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="IniciarTarefa" id="acao"></label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <button id="IniciarTarefa" name="IniciarTarefa" class="btn btn-info">Iniciar Tarefa</button>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="mostrar">Mostrar quando tarefa foi iniciada</button>
```

Mas mostra a data desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E desta forma não consigo inserir na base de dados. Pretendia que mostrasse só a data desta forma:

**2019-03-22 17:14:45**

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como formatar data no javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6526/como-formatar-data-no-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando função demonstrada em outra resposta em ingles (fonte [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date))

```js
 function formatDate(date) {
  var monthNames = [
"Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março",
"Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho",
"Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro",
"Novembro", "Dezembro"
  ];

  var day = date.getDate();
  var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var min = date.getMinutes();
  var sec = date.getSeconds();

  return year + '-' + (monthIndex+1) + '-' + day + ' ' + hours + ':' + min + ':' + sec;
}


var dtTime;
$('#IniciarTarefa').on('click', function () {
   $(this).closest('.form-group').data('inicio', formatDate( new Date() ) );
});

$('#mostrar').on('click', function () {
    var time = $('.form-group').data('inicio');
    alert('Data: '+ time );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="IniciarTarefa" id="acao"></label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <button id="IniciarTarefa" name="IniciarTarefa" class="btn btn-info">Iniciar Tarefa</button>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="mostrar">Mostrar quando tarefa foi iniciada</button>
```

Comment: mas pretendia que guardasse do value do botão além da data também a hora

Comment: Ok, adicionado.
Para mais opções, consultar documentação da classe Date: https://javascript.info/date

Comment: mas da forma que está só quando mostra é que a data é formatada, mas  o botão mostrar e a função do `click` do botão mostrar é para retirar. A ideia é guardar no `value` do botão com `id="IniciarTarefa"` a data e a hora formatada para depois inserir na tabela da base de dados.

Comment: Cara, você já tem a faca e o queijo na mão, pode manipular o codigo como quiser, de qualquer forma, script ajustado.

Answer (score 0):

**Boa tarde. Isto pode ajudar:**

```js
$('.jsData').on('click',()=>{
    obtainedData();
})


function obtainedData(){
  var fecha = new Date();
var options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric',hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second:'numeric' };

alert(
  fecha.toLocaleDateString("pt-BR", options)
);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="jsData">Obtained Date</button>
```