# Converter data yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.z para dd/mm/aaaa com javascript

Tags: javascript

Como converter a data de `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.z` para `dd/mm/aaaa`?

**Exemplo:** `2018-07-19T22:07:00.000-03:00` para `19/07/2018`

Procurei por todo lugar (incluindo o stackoverflow em ingles e português) uma solução pra isso com javascript, só achei com outras linguagens.

Comment: Da uma olhada aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6526/como-formatar-data-no-javascript

Comment: Nada nesse post me ajuda ja que pega a data atual e não uma data pre definida

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode criar uma nova instância da classe [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) passando a *string* da data ao construtor e usar os métodos da instância para criar a data formatada.

> **Nota:** A *string* passada como primeiro argumento para o construtor da classe deve seguir um padrão. Para saber mais, veja [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Suporte_ao_formato_ECMAScript_5_ISO-86010).

Após criar a instância, use os métodos [`getDate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate), [`getMonth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) e [`getFullYear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/) para acessar o dia, mês e ano respectivamente. Algo assim:

```js
const date = new Date('2018-07-19T22:07:00.000-03:00')

const day = date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0')
const month = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0')
const year = date.getFullYear()

const formatted = `${day}/${month}/${year}`

console.log(formatted)
```

Algumas observações em relação ao código:

- Criei uma função `padNum` para adicionar um `0` em dias ou meses que não tiverem duas casas numéricas.
- Devemos somar um ao número retornado em `getMonth` (linha 9), já que esse método retorna os meses iniciando no índice 0:

  - Janeiro ⇒ `0`;
  - Fevereiro ⇒ `1`;
  - `...`;
  - Dezembro ⇒ `11`.