# Formatar data JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, data

A data é preenchida de acordo com a informação obtida de uma resposta JSON

Script

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#@(Model.Campo)_Nome").typeahead({
        source: function (query, process) {
            return $.get('@Url.Action("PesquisarAlgumaCoisa", "AlgumaCoisa")', { nome: query, somenteAtivas: '@Model.SomenteAtivas' }, function (data) {
                return process(data);
            }, "json");
        },
        autoSelect: true
    }).change(function (event) {
        var current = $(event.target).typeahead("getActive");
        $("#@Model.Campo").val("");
        $(".dataFim").html("");
        if (current && current.name == $(event.target).val()) {
            $("#@Model.Campo").val(current.id);
            $(".dataFim").html(dataFormatada(current.DataFim));

        }
    });
 function dataFormatada(data){
        dia  = data.getDate().toString(),
        diaF = (dia.length == 1) ? '0'+dia : dia,
        mes  = (data.getMonth()+1).toString(), //+1 pois no getMonth Janeiro começa com zero.
        mesF = (mes.length == 1) ? '0'+mes : mes,
        anoF = data.getFullYear();
    return diaF+"/"+mesF+"/"+anoF;
```

[image: Perceba que a data vem em formato americano]

Já tentei de de algumas formas, como:

```
 $(".dataFim").html(current.DataFim.toString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
 $(".dataFim").html(current.DataFim.toLocaleTimeString());
```

[image: magem]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Como formatar data no javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6526/como-formatar-data-no-javascript)

Comment: @IcaroMartins não, apresenta outro erro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para resolver este caso, converti para string e realizei a formatação

```
   $(".dataFim").html(current.DataFim.toString().substr(0, 10).split('-').reverse().join('/'));
```