# Formatar data do banco para javascript

Tags: javascript, data

estou montando uma tabela no datatables com informações de data e hora. Mas os dados vêm no banco no padrão YYYY-mm-dd. Como faço pra alterar e mostrar no datatable como dd/mm/YYYY?

Meu código:

```
function retornarColetas(data) {
            var coletas = "";
                            
            $.each(data, function (chave, valor) {
                coletas += '<tr>' +
                        '<td>' + valor.id_coleta + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + valor.cliente + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + valor.data + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + valor.hora + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + valor.vendedor + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + valor.status + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' +
                        '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info text-info mr-2"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i> Editar</a>' +
                        '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger text-danger"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i> Excluir</a>' +
                        '</td>';
            });
            $('#tabelaColeta').html(coletas);

        }
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como formatar data no javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6526/como-formatar-data-no-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumindo que seu `data` venha nesse formato: `2020-10-20`, voce pode fazer(de uma maneira bem direta) um `split()`, logo em seguida um `reverse()`([veja aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)), e por fim fazer `join()`.

Ficaria assim:

```js
const data = '2020-10-20'.split('-').reverse().join('/');

console.log(data);
```

O que acontece:

- Voce separa a *string* em um *array* com o `split()`: `['2020', '10', '20']`;
- Voce reverte o *array* com `reverse()`: `['20','10','2020']`;
- E faz um `join()` usando o `/`: `20/10/2020`

Seu codigo ficaria assim:

```
 $.each(data, function (chave, valor) {
                var dataFormatada = valor.data.split('-').reverse().join('/');

                coletas += '<tr>' +
                        '<td>' + valor.id_coleta + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + valor.cliente + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + dataFormatada + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + valor.hora + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + valor.vendedor + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + valor.status + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' +
                        '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info text-info mr-2"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i> Editar</a>' +
                        '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger text-danger"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i> Excluir</a>' +
                        '</td>';
            });
            $('#tabelaColeta').html(coletas);
```

Comment: Perfeito. Muito obrigado pela ajuda! Nota 10!