# Como converter essa string data "2021-09-22T09:00:00" em formato padrão

Tags: javascript, string, regex, data

Recebo essa string numa request `"2021-09-22T09:00:00"`

Preciso transforma-la nesse padrão com `22/09/2021 09:00` com JavaScript

Alguém pode me ajudar? Preciso de um regex pra modificar

Comment: Basicamente, crie a data com `var data = new Date("2021-09-22T09:00:00")` e depois escolha algum método descrito nas várias respostas existentes nos links indicados acima no box azul. Atenção para os métodos que usam os *getters* (`getMonth()`, `getHours()`, etc) versus `toISOString()`, pois há um detalhe importante explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/494302/112052) (com relação a "horário local" x UTC)

Comment: Aproveitando, **não** use regex, é o pior jeito de fazer (as maneiras que estão nos links indicados são melhores). Sobre o uso de regex para validar datas, eu comento um pouco [nesta resposta](/a/363711/112052) e na segunda metade [desta outra resposta](/a/360903/112052), e também há exemplos [nesta pergunta](/q/272539/112052). Mas talvez seja melhor seguir a recomendação [desta resposta](/a/272541/112052) e em vez de regex, usar os recursos da linguagem que são específicos para tratar datas.