# Formatar uma data pra string em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, data

Tenho a seguinte data:

```
Tue Dec 21 2021 09:00:00 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)
```

A pergunta é como faço pra deixar ela numa string parecida com essa?:

```
"09:00:00"
```

Se alguém souber como resolver com DateFNS seria bacana, mas qualquer jeito ajuda!

Comment: O link indicado acima tem uma resposta, basta adaptar para ter somente o horário. Também dá para adaptar [isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/494302/112052), usando `toLocaleTimeString` em vez de `toLocaleDateString`

Answer (score 1):

Date-fns utiliza o objeto Date nativo, o que facilita muito.
Código compatível com node:

```
var format = require('date-fns/format')  // ou import { format } from 'date-fns';    
const minhaDataString = 'Tue Dec 21 2021 09:00:00 GMT-0300';
const meuObjetoData = new Date(minhaDataString);
const dataFormatada = format(meuObjetoData, 'HH:mm');
```

[Documentação sobre a função format](https://date-fns.org/v2.27.0/docs/format)